# how to create API key for GCM?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have problem in creating API Key because the options "create new server key" and "create new browser key " were not in the API access page. whether I should pay for using that.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Normally after creating a project and saving a project # you click on Services on the left panel and turn on Google Cloud Messaging for Android. Then you should see this screen: [image]

Click on API Access and note down the API Key marked on the picture

[image]

**EDIT:**
Here is the link to the full article that describes this process in details:
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Comment: Why don't you give credits to actual author? Here is detailed article about [Android GCM](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)

Comment: Yes, this is plagiarism. This is very bad form. If I had time I would overhaul this answer.

Answer (score 9):

The screenshots previously posts provide a great visual, but here are the steps I've taken when setting it up:

Go to http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html

1 - Login with a google account

2 - Click 'Create project...' if you have not already done so.

3 - When you get to a page with a left side nav, make sure 'Services' is selected

4 - Turn 'Google Cloud Messaging for Android' ON

5 - Click on the 'Google Cloud Messaging for Android' link

6 - Click on the 'API Access' link in the left nav

7 - You should now be able to create a new server or browser key by clicking the corresponding button

Comment: Yay I setup all stuff but I forget to `Turn 'Google Cloud Messaging for Android' ON`

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way is now login with your account on: https://developers.google.com/mobile/add and use wizard :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all create Project in Google Console https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=cloudconsole&passive=true&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fconsole.developers.google.com%2Fproject&ltmpl=cloudconsole

Create New Project and note down the Project Number

In the left pane under APIs & auth select APIs and enable Google Cloud Messaging for Android.

Then select Credentials section.

Create a new Key select type as Server key. Enter the IP of your server. If you are testing in **localhost** enter the IP as 0.0.0.0/0.

Note down the API Key

Answer (score 1):

- Go to [Google play
  console](https://console.developers.google.com/project?authuser=0)
- Then click Create project and provide an ID for this application.
- Then you can see the project name shown in the list.Enter into the
  project you were created earlier.
- In the left side, **Api&Auth** ->Api.You have to turn on `Google
  cloud messaging for android`.
- For me,I have to Click `Credentials` in `Api&Auth` to create a
  key.Below I am shown a screenshot for that.

  [image]
- Finally,Click `create new key` to generate a key for your
  application.see here for [SHA-1 fingerprint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727912/sha-1-fingerprint-of-keystore-certificate)