# SHA-1 fingerprint of keystore certificate

Tags: android, google-maps, google-plus, sha1, android-keystore

Is the method for getting an SHA-1 fingerprint the same as the method of getting the fingerprint? Previously, I was running this command:

[image: Windows Command Prompt running keytool.exe]

It's not clear to me if the result I'm getting is the SHA-1 fingerprint. Can somebody clarify this?

Comment: Hope this link will help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214467/how-to-obtain-signing-certificate-fingerprint-sha1-for-oauth-2-0-on-android/32558627#32558627

Comment: Easiest way to Get SHA-1 For Release and Debug mode android studio gradle. [Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727912/sha-1-fingerprint-of-keystore-certificate/35308827#35308827)

Comment: run this command in your terminal:  keytool -exportcert -list -v \
-alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore.  It will ask for your keystore password. which you can find from the file named "debug.keystore.properties" in the android/keystore folder

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CPAxGzZ4pi8

Comment: I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-get-the-sha-1-fingerprint-certificate-for-debug-mode-in-android-studio-c9df7ae2401b) will definitely help.

Answer (score 1234, accepted):

Follow [this](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/12/displaying-sha1-certificate-fingerprint.html) tutorial for creating SHA1 fingerprint for Google Map v2

For Debug mode:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

for Release mode:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore {keystore_name} -alias {alias_name}
```

example:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\MG\Desktop\test.jks -alias test
```

> On windows, when **keytool command is not found**, Go to your installed JDK Directory e.g. `<YourJDKPath>\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\bin\`, open command line and try the above commands for debug/release mode.

Another way of getting your SHA1 OR SHA-256 use `./gradlew signingReport`

For more detailed info visit
[Using Gradle's Signing Report](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth#using_gradles_signing_report)

Comment: ~/ is your home directory in *nix systems. Under Windows, just use  %USERPROFILE%

Comment: If you're writing Android apps on Xamarin, use this:

keytool -list -v -keystore "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android/debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android

Comment: how to get release sha1. I am getting it from my app.jks but console.google is showing its already used.

Comment: $ keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -storepass android 

only this also works

Comment: Look at this to get SHA-1 key using android studio.
http://easybook4u.com/index.php/2017/08/25/how-to-get-sha-1-key-using-android-studio/

Comment: do you also know how to remove it?

Comment: your solution is working fine. why the heck, google official documentation doesnt work? coment defiined here wont execute and return error. https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth

Comment: after generating releasemode api key for sha1 for google places api for android place picker map opened and closed immediately.In log showing forbidden error 403 please help me

Comment: Give example for debug please

Comment: I just created a .bat for convenience:

??@echo off
??title SHA-1 from release keystore 
??color 0a 
??cd C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre 
??set /p keystorePath= Set the path to the keystore here (just drag it here): 
??set /p alias= Enter the keystore alias: 
??echo : 
??echo : 
??echo : 
??keytool -list -v -keystore %keystorePath% -alias %alias% 
??echo : 
??echo : 
??echo : 
??set /p cmd=Press any key to exit

Create a .bat file,  paste this code, replace the "??" by line breaks and change JRE path if needed.

Comment: There are archive snapshots of [the tutorial referenced above](http://web.archive.org/web/20130515000000*/http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/12/displaying-sha1-certificate-fingerprint.html).

Comment: Just for future reference: make sure you point to `~/.android/debug.keystore` file. As I already had a keystore file, I thought I should reference it or create a new one in order to make this command work properly.

Answer (score 744):

If you are using android studio use simple step

1. Run your project
2. Click on Gradle menu
3. Expand Gradle `Tasks` tree
4. Double click on `android` -> `signingReport` and see the magic
5. It will tell you everything on the Run tab

[image]

Result Under **Run Tab** If Android Studio < 2.2
[image]

**From android studio 2.2**
Result will be available under Run console but use highlighted toggle button

[image]

Or 
Second Way is
Create new project in android studio New -> Google Maps Activity

[image]

then open google_maps_api.xml xml file as shown in pics you will see your SHA key
[image]

Comment: My 'gradle projects' window is empty... any ideas why that might be?

Comment: It will appear once you run the project either in emulator or on device

Comment: Yea I tried that but nothing happened. Seems as though, in my case, I had to press the 'refresh' button before anything showed up!

Comment: For all Android devs, this is quite an easy way to find the SHA1. Nice finding man.

Comment: is sha1 key same for all the apps? or different for every app?

Comment: @anwar Hossain Every time you generate SHA1 It can be different every time irrespective of app. I have tried two different days it has given me different

Comment: @LokeshTiwari I think on Android Studio 2.1 the ```signReport``` task is in ```Tasks -> android```

Comment: @AdnanAli Thank you for pointing out. Yes it is available in 2.2 but use **Toggle button in Run Console** check updated pic

Comment: plus 1 for toggle task execution/text mode :D

Comment: It now appears under "Gradle Console" tab from Android studio 2.2.3

Comment: The google Maps activity idea is the BEST. Thank you

Comment: @onexf go to build variants >> change debug to release

Comment: I've followed the steps in this answer and it works great. But how to change the Gradle setting back to whatever it was so that when I click the **Run** button in Android Studio, it installs and runs the app on my device/emulator as it did previously?

Comment: ...solution to my **Run** problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48283047/1617737 .

Comment: It's the best solution for Android Developers who work on Windows because keytool is not works in Windows console.

Comment: Works fine, thanks for this answer. However, I am curious if I can use this to get SHA1 for release key of my app. (the default is debug key)

Answer (score 210):

**Easiest way for getting SHA1 Key in android studio both (Debug and release Mode)**

1. Open `Android Studio`
2. Open Your Project
3. Click on **Gradle** (From **Right Side Panel**, you will see **Gradle Bar**)
4. Click on **Refresh** (Click on Refresh from Gradle Bar , you will see List Gradle scripts of your Project)
5. Click on Your Project (Your Project Name form List)
6. Click on Tasks/Android
7. Double Click on `signingReport` (You will get `SHA1` and `MD5` in Run Bar)

**If you are using new Android Studio it shows time to execute on top there is Toggle task execution mode click on that you will get you SHA-1 key. Check 2nd and 3rd reference images.**

[image: Check image for details]
[image][image]

**Generate SHA-1 for Release Mode**

1-First add keystore config in your gradle [How to add config in gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25001479/app-release-unsigned-apk-is-not-signed/34964168#34964168).

2-After Adding Config in gradle change build variant. [image]

3-Then Follow Above Procedure you will get SHA-1 for release mode.

4-Check Image. [image]

Comment: How to change the location? I know how to change to a different keystore when signing, but what about the default one?

Comment: very detailed answer with images, helps a lot... very easy to understand than other answers here... up-vote for the images in answer

Answer (score 90):

Go to your java bin directory via the cmd:

**C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin>**

Now type in the below comand in your cmd:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "c:\users\your_user_name\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

Comment: thanks I used password as "android" that solved this issue

Answer (score 46):

[image: ![Go to far left[![][1][1]]

Please refer to the following images and get the SHA-1 key
[image: Refresh]

[image: View in console panel at bottom]

Comment: Agree: best option. "Plused" one. I missed a l little bit more text information, but the main path you've shown. Thank you.

Comment: 1)You have to double click on the filename.

Answer (score 45):

If you are using eclipse, go to:
*Window->Preferences->Android->Build* 
You will find what you are looking there.

[image]

Comment: Where can I find the equivalent on Android Studio? My IDE is pointing to the wrong SHA1

Answer (score 45):

### An easy answer. To find SH1 in the new Android Studio Version. Do these simple steps.

> **Step 1** Go to setting and you can also press **CTRL + ALT + S**

#### Edit

**Step 2** for latest android studio including - **Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1**

> Go to **Experimental** and then **UnTick** the option named **Only include test tasks in the Gradle task list generated during Gradle Sync** if it is **Ticked** and then press ok

**Step 2** for older versions of the android studio -

> Go to **Experimental** and then **UnTick** the option named **Do not build Gradle task during Gradle sync** if it is Ticked and then press ok

#### Continue

> **Step 3** Go to **File** then choose the option of **Sync Project with Gradle files**

> **Step 4** Click on **Gradle** on the right side of panel then **Tasks** then **android** then double click on **signingReport**

### Then you will get the SH1 fingerprint

[image]

Comment: Thanks, This is best answer for latest android studio.

Comment: this one, yes - is a comment worth the highest possible grade. In addition to being correct, he explains everything in detail.

Answer (score 40):

Run the following command to get your sha1: `keytool -v -list -keystore "< debug.keystore path >"`
If you do not know the path of `debug.keystore`, you may find your `debug.keystore` path by checking `windows-->preferences-->android-->build`

I prepared step by step tutorial to show how you can use google map android v2 on emulator(android 4.2.2)
have a look at to my blog: http://umut.tekguc.info/en/content/google-android-map-v2-step-step

Answer (score 39):

I saw lots of posts about this issue, so I will keep it simple + examples.

To get the SHA1 for ClientID for Sign In with Google+ and more actions:

**General Form:**

```
keytool -list -v -keystore <your_keystore_full_path> -alias <your_alias_name>
```

**For Debug, replace with your debug.keystore path, for Example :**

```
keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\DAVID\.android\debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey
```

Password: android

**For Release, replace with your keystore path and alias password, for Example :**

```
keytool -list -v -keystore C:\ProjectsData\keystore\my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name
```

Password: Your alias password.

Comment: Works great! I have included both a DEBUG and a RELEASE key in console.developer.google.com. Not sure if both are really needed. Nevertheless it works great, after spending 4 hours on this G**gle feature.

Comment: If your alias key have space like "App Moon" then add double quation "App Moon" as alias name.

Comment: the best and working solution , for google clientID i needed SHA-1 in release mode , other solutions give us the SHA-1 in debug mode

Answer (score 35):

This is step by step process of what worked for me.

First run the app then follow steps below (also shown in screenshot)

1. click signing report
2. open gradle console dialog
3. it should display your SHA-1 certificate number

[image]

Comment: A true savior! I don't know why the SHA-1 key was different when generated from command prompt and android studio.

Comment: it shows sha1 for debug, is this same for release variant also ?

Comment: @SanketPatel are u got the release SHA1?

Comment: nope, actually i resolved my issue so stopped searching for it @Oliver

Answer (score 30):

Using *Google Play app signing feature* & Google APIs integration in your app?

1. If you are using Google Play App Signing, don't forget that release signing-certificate fingerprint needed for Google API credentials is not the regular upload signing keys (SHA-1) you obtain from your app by this method:

[image: Upload signing certificate]

2. You can obtain your release SHA-1 only from App signing page of your Google Play console as shown below:-

If you use Google Play app signing, Google re-signs your app. Thats how your signing-certificate fingerprint is given by Google Play App Signing as shown below:

[image: App Signing page - Google Play Console]

Read more [How to get Release SHA-1 (Signing-certificate fingerprint) if using 'Google Play app signing'](https://publishingfirstandroidapp.blogspot.com/2017/07/google-play-app-signing-how-to-get.html)

Answer (score 27):

For ***Android Studio 4.2*** and newer version ,follows these steps to generate ***SHA Key*** . Steps are given in these pictures.

***Steps:-***

**1)** Click on the **gradle**. Top right on the **Android Studio**. As you can see in this picture.

[image: Step1]

**2)** Now click on **icon** as seen in below picture. A new **searchable windows/screen will open**.

[image: SHA2]

**3)** Now type,***gradle signingreport*** and press **Enter**  to start generating **SHA KEY** as seen in below picture.

[image: sha3]

**4)** **Your **SHA Key** will generate as seen in this picture. Using these steps you can generate SHA KEY in Android Studio 4.2.**

[image: sha4]

Comment: got error missing keystore

Comment: @Adnanhaider  have you tried all steps carefully ? Its valid in latest version of android studio. If you are using old version then open gradle then app and then android and last click of signing report

Comment: my bad i used release config that's why i got error. now its work fine thanks

Answer (score 20):

from a Debug Keystore we can get the **SHA1** value in `Eclipse`. Accessing from the menu:
`Window` -> `Preferences` -> `Android` -> `Build`

but it doesn´t work for a production `Keystore`.
[image]

So, to get the **SHA1** value from a production Keystore go to:
`Android Tools` -> `Export Signed Application Package`. Follow the process for signing your apk and the SHA1 will showed as a certificate.

[image]

Answer (score 17):

> keytool is a key and certificate management utility. It allows users
>   to administer their own public/private key pairs and associated
>   certificates for use in self-authentication (where the user
>   authenticates himself/herself to other users/services) or data
>   integrity and authentication services, using digital signatures.

**For Windows**

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "%USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

**Other**

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

Authorization on Android uses a **SHA1 fingerprint and package name** to identify your app instead of a **client ID and client secret**.

[image]

> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html

Answer (score 11):

**Best way ever with all steps:**

**For Release Keystore SHA1 Key**:

1. Open Command Prompt
2. `C:\Users\hiren.patel>cd..`
3. `C:\Users>cd..`
4. `C:\>cd "Program Files"`
5. `C:\Program Files>cd Java`
6. `C:\Program Files\Java>cd jdk_version_code`
7. `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk_version_code>cd bin`
8. `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk_version_code\bin>keytool -list -v -keystore "D:\Hiren Data\My Root Folder\My Project Folder\keystore_title.jks" -alias my_alias_name -storepass my_store_password -keypass my_key_password`

**Replace** below thing:

1. `jdk_version_code`
2. `D:\Hiren Data\My Root Folder\My Project Folder\keystore_title.jks`
3. `my_alias_name`
4. `my_store_password`
5. `my_key_password`

**Done**

Answer (score 11):

In Gnu/Linux

**First**

You need key.jks, for example in my case this file it's in folder in /Desktop/Keys

```
/Desktop/Keys/key.jks
```

**Second**

`cd /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64`

Now you need excecute this command

```
keytool -list -v -keystore /PATH/file.jks -alias YourAlias -storepass *** -keypass ***
```

remplacing this fields

```
-keystore
-alias
-storepass
-keypass
```

For example

```
 keytool -list -v -keystore /home/david/Desktop/Keys/key.jks -alias MyAlias -storepass 456 -keypass 123
```

[image]

**Good Luck!!**

Answer (score 11):

on the new update just go to `Android` folder and type `./gradlew signingReport`

Answer (score 9):

**Step 1 :** First locate your **JDK's** **bin** folder in your windows pc. See the image below.

Mine is :

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin
```

[image]

Step 2 : Now search for **Command Prompt** by typing **"cmd"** in windows 10 search bar. Then open **Command Prompt** as **Administrator** mode. 
See the image below:

[image]

**Step 3 :** Now copy this path and type it into Command Prompt

```
 C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin
```

[image]

In Command Prompt :

```
cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin
```

[image]

After pressing **Enter** button you will go to the bin folder.

[image]

Your setup is done. Now generate your SHA1 key for Release mode.

**Release SHA1 Key :**

```
keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\Turzo\Desktop\earninglearning.keystore -alias turzo -storepass 12345678 -keypass 12345678
```

[image]

Comment: Screenshots were quite helpful

Answer (score 8):

First there is same `.jar` file that in `fb-sdk android-support-v4.jar`.
Then generate `SHA1` key using:

```
PackageInfo info;
try {

    info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
        "com.example.worldmission", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);

    for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
        MessageDigest md;
        md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        md.update(signature.toByteArray());
        String something = new String(Base64.encode(md.digest(), 0));
        Log.e("Hash key", something);
        System.out.println("Hash key" + something);
    }

} catch (NameNotFoundException e1) {
    Log.e("name not found", e1.toString());
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    Log.e("no such an algorithm", e.toString());
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("exception", e.toString());
}
```

Comment: Nothing to do with certificates whatsoever.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using Android Studio IDE then you can get SHA1 has value for your all build variants with one click.

Under Gradle Projects Window > **Select Root Project** > **signingReport** > **double click**

[image: File Navigation]

Next

[image: Open Run Window]

Go To Variant: **release** for release

Go To Variant: **debug** for debug

Comment: I do it but i dont got the SHA for release !

Comment: Please make sure you have added sign in credential in the sign in configuration under release block in gradle. Otherwise it wont show release sha key

Answer (score 8):

[image]

**Right side Gradle --> signing project  get all keys**

Answer (score 7):

Open Command Prompt in Windows and go to the following folder .

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin

Use commands `cd <next directory name>` to change directory to next.
Use command `cd ..` to change directory to the Prev

Now type the following command as it is :

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "%USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

Comment: After battling with this issue for SEVERAL hours, your answer saved my app's life. THANKS!!!!

Answer (score 7):

//the simplest way to get SHA1

//add following command to your terminal and hit enter

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

Answer (score 6):

You can get *MD5* and *SHA1* fingerprint for any workspace by going to `Window>Preference>Android>Build` in *Eclipse*.

Comment: this will do the job instead of going through the hassle of exporting and using CMD

Answer (score 6):

In Addition to [Lokesh Tiwar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33479550/3849039)

For release builds add the following in the gradle:

```
android {

defaultConfig{
//Goes here
}

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("PATH TO THE KEY_STORE FILE")
            storePassword "PASSWORD"
            keyAlias "ALIAS_NAME"
            keyPassword "KEY_PASSWORD"
        }
    }
buildTypes {
        release {
            zipAlignEnabled true
            minifyEnabled false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}
```

Now running the signingReport as in Lokesh's Answer would show the SHA 1 and MD5 keys for the release builds as well.

[image: Sample]

Comment: you are the boss!! :)

Answer (score 6):

This solution is for android studio 3.5 version:

1. Open your project into Android studio.
2. Click on Gradle tab on right side.
3. Will see two things one is our project(root) and just app.
4. Select our project in your case it might be your app.
5. Right click on the project and refresh it.
6. Then click on the the project drop don button.
7. Click on the Tasks where will see android folder.
8. Double Click on signingReport  and will see the details in Run console.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using android studio use simple steps:

- Run your project
- Click on Gradle menu
- Expand Gradle task tree
- Click on android-> signingReport

[image]
If there is nothing displayed(android studio 2.2) then

#### Click on `Toggle tasks execution/text mode` from Run bar

Comment: bro in the current version it will maybe not work.

Answer (score 5):

As of `Sept 2020`, if you want to get the **SHA-1 fingerprint of keystore certificate** of `Release`. Simply open up your `Google Play Developer Console` and open the `App Signing` tab.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This is the solution for **macOS Ventura 13.0 on MacBook Pro M2 2022**

I needed SHA1 key for Google Cloud.

1. Run this command in your terminal where your project is. I was working on a Flutter project.

`keytool -keystore path-to-debug-or-production-keystore -list -v`

If it doesn't work and you get this error, follow along.

[image]

2. Go to https://www.java.com and download and install the latest version of Java. Run the above command again, if you get another error like this follow along.

[image]

3. Run this command and this will give you SHA1, SHA256, MD5 for default debug key. And it can be used for developing and debugging with google play services.

`keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android`

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I had a problem during opening with command

```
[keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\MG\Desktop\test.jks -alias test]
```

Therefore, i download https://sourceforge.net/projects/portecle/.
Then just open .jks file from the jar program. it will show you all relevant information

[image: snapshot of the program]

Answer (score 4):

#### Easy method - with Keystore explorer

### Follow the step

1. Download keystore explorer [Download link](https://keystore-explorer.org/)
2. Install keystore explorer
3. Open keystore via keystore explorer
4. Enter password
5. Click your keystore name
6. then you will get the sha1 key

Answer (score 4):

Many ways to get SHA1 and SHA-256 key .
To generate the SHA-1 key for your Android app, there are a few alternative methods:

**Using Keytool Command-Line Tool:** You can use the keytool command-line tool that comes with the Java Development Kit (JDK) to generate the SHA-1 key. Open a terminal or command prompt and navigate to your JDK's bin directory. Then run the following command:
bash

```
keytool -list -v -keystore your_keystore_file.jks -alias your_alias_name
```

Replace your_keystore_file.jks with the path to your keystore file and your_alias_name with the alias you used to sign your app.

**Using Android Studio:** Android Studio provides a straightforward way to get the SHA-1 key. Follow these steps:
Click on the "Gradle" tab on the right side of the Android Studio window.
Navigate to "Your Project" -> "Tasks" -> "Android" -> "signingReport".
Double-click on "signingReport" to run the task, which will output the SHA-1 key and other signing information in the "Run" pane.
Using Google Play Console: If you have already uploaded your app to the Google Play Console, you can find the SHA-1 key in the "Release management" -> **"App signing"** section.

**Using Online Tools:** There are some online tools available where you can upload your keystore file and get the SHA-1 key as a result. However, for security reasons, it's generally better to generate the SHA-1 key locally using trusted tools like the ones mentioned above.

**Using Gradle Plugin:** You can also use the Gradle Signing Report Plugin to get the SHA-1 key. Add the following to your app's build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'signing-report'

signingReport {
    // You can configure signing configs here if needed
}
```

Then run the signingReport Gradle task. You will find the SHA-1 key printed in the console.
All these methods will provide you with the SHA-1 key needed for various purposes, such as integrating Google services or configuring API access. Choose the one that fits your workflow and security requirements best.

Answer (score 3):

I am using Ubuntu 12.0.4 and I have get the Certificate fingerprints in this way for release key store on command prompt
after  generate keystore file , you can use this key for  released app ,if you are using  google map in your app ,so this can show the map properly inside app after release,, i got the result on command prompt below

```html
administrator@user:~$ keytool -list -v -keystore /home/administrator/mykeystore/mykeystore.jks -alias myprojectalias

 
Enter keystore password:  ******

Alias name: myprojectalias

Creation date: 22 Apr, 2014

Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry

Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=xyz, OU= xyz, O= xyz, L= xyz, ST= xyz, C=91
Issuer: CN= xyz, OU= xyz, O= xyz, L= xyz, ST= xyz, C=91

Serial number: 7c4rwrfdff
Valid from: Fri Apr 22 11:59:55 IST 2014 until: Tue Apr 14 11:59:55 IST 2039

Certificate fingerprints:
     MD5:  95:A2:4B:3A:0D:40:23:FF:F1:F3:45:26:F5:1C:CE:86
     SHA1: DF:95:Y6:7B:D7:0C:CD:25:04:11:54:FA:40:A7:1F:C5:44:94:AB:90
     SHA276: 00:7E:B6:EC:55:2D:C6:C9:43:EE:8A:42:BB:5E:14:BB:33:FD:A4:A8:B8:5C:2A:DE:65:5C:A3:FE:C0:14:A8:02
     Signature algorithm name: SHA276withRSA
     Version: 2

Extensions: 

 ObjectId: 2.6.28.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 1E A1 57 F2 81 AR 57 D6   AC 54 65 89 E0 77 65 D9  ..W...Q..Tb..W6.
0010: 3B 38 9C E1
```

On Windows Platform we can get the keystore for debug mode by using the below way

```html
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin>keytool -l
.android\debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -s
id
Alias name: androiddebugkey
Creation date: Oct 21, 2016
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: C=US, O=Android, CN=Android Debug
Issuer: C=US, O=Android, CN=Android Debug
Serial number: 1
Valid from: Fri Oct 21 00:50:00 IST 2016 until: S
Certificate fingerprints:
         MD5:  86:E3:2E:D7:0E:22:D6:23:2E:D8:E7:E
         SHA1: B4:6F:BE:13:AA:FF:E5:AB:58:20:A9:B
         SHA256: 15:88:E2:1E:42:6F:61:72:02:44:68
56:49:4C:32:D6:17:34:A6:7B:A5:A6
         Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA
```

Comment: Another way you can get this certification detail for debug mode from
(1)Right click on Gradle bar at android studio
(2)then click on app -> Tasks -> android -> signingReports
then on Gradle console you will get the reports

Answer (score 3):

If you are using [Google Play App Signing](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en), instead of getting the SHA from the keystore, an easier way is to go to the Google Play Console > Your app > Release Management > App signing and look for your upload certificate.

[image: Screenshot of the page where you get this info]

Comment: here showing 2 signin certificates appsignin and uploaded signincertificates.which one i need to use for release

Comment: For release you need to use the App signing certificate

Answer (score 3):

if you have not the Keystore and alias you can use this command :

```
keytool -list -printcert -jarfile app.apk
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using React Native, debug.keystore is in `android/app`, but may not be in `~/.android`.

Set debug.keystore path as the following:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore {PROJECT_ROOT}/android/app/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

Console will print something like this:

```
Alias name: androiddebugkey
Creation date: Jan 1, 2014
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=Android Debug, OU=Android, O=Unknown, L=Unknown, ST=Unknown, C=US
Issuer: CN=Android Debug, OU=Android, O=Unknown, L=Unknown, ST=Unknown, C=US
Serial number: 2==Serial Number==2
Valid from: Wed Jan 01 06:35:04 CST 2014 until: Wed May 01 06:35:04 CST 2052
Certificate fingerprints:
     SHA1: 5E:=========== SHA1 SIGNING KEY ===========:25
     SHA256: FA:============ SHA 256 ===================9C
Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA
Subject Public Key Algorithm: 2048-bit RSA key
Version: 3
```

Answer (score 3):

In the recent update of Android Studio 4.2, we are unable to get the file: signing report. So, we can get this again by following the following steps:

```
File -> Settings -> Experimental -> 
Now we need to uncheck the *do not build Gradle list during Gradle sync* ->
Click Ok -> now again go to File -> Click on *Sync Project with Gradle files*
```

Now you can follow, what other answers tell.

Thanks to @PapayaCoders Youtube channel to resolve this issue. Here is the [link of the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rfyongdas4k) concerning this problem.

Answer (score 3):

A simpler method is to run `./gradlew signingReport` in your project root directory
Other methods are explained in this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-get-the-sha-1-fingerprint-certificate-for-debug-mode-in-android-studio-c9df7ae2401b)

Answer (score 3):

In Flutter Project continue in vs code and paste this command

set your username

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "c:\users\your_pc_username\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Android studio this very simple.

Create a new Google map activity and you can see sha1 fingerprint like below image.

[image: New Google Map aCTIVITY]

[image: YOU CAN SEE SHA1 IN BELOW IMAGE]

Answer (score 2):

use android studio embedded Java jre location, for windows user below screenshot may help to find SHA1

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First go to jar file copy the keytool path then add into system path then run.. i hope this one is worked..

Answer (score 1):

For local you get easily sha1 from android studio but for live please check below url :

[Facebook Android Generate Key Hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306009/facebook-android-generate-key-hash)

We mostly not done below steps so please check the link which is 100% correct.

```
8) If you see in openssl Bin folder, you will get a file with the name of debug.txt
```

9) Now either you can restart command prompt or work with existing command prompt

10) get back to C drive and give the path of openssl Bin folder

11) copy the following code and paste

```
openssl sha1 -binary debug.txt > debug_sha.txt
```

12) you will get debug_sha.txt in openssl bin folder

13) Again copy following code and paste

```
openssl base64 -in debug_sha.txt > debug_base64.txt
```

14) you will get debug_base64.txt in openssl bin folder

15) open debug_base64.txt file Here is your Key hash.

Answer (score 1):

Try this with your user & pass

> keytool -list -v -keystore {path of jks file} -alias {keyname} -storepass {keypassword} -keypass {aliaspassword}

Exe

> keytool -list -v -keystore "E:\AndroidStudioProject\ParathaApp\key.jks" -alias key0 -storepass mks@1 -keypass golu@1

Answer (score 1):

[![Change the build variant then you can see the run the application which will lead to error

You have to find SHA1 code for Release Key & enter it on your Developer Console. ( for me developer console is firebase some people might use different services) To find SHA1 Code . easy way is

Go to Build --- Select Build Variant -- On the left Side Select "Release" as build variant -- now go to module settings ( or try to run project , android studio will tell you about a error and click fix error button) --- Select Signing tab --- add your release key and passwords -- now goto build types -- select release -- on signing config select your release key config -- now run your project -- now run your signing report --- you can find SHA1 under release build -- enter that sha1 code on your developer console

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image: That's it]

Answer (score 1):

[image: please try this]

**go to Gradle -> click no elephant icon and write signingReport and click enter done**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

At ANDROID STUDIO do the following steps:

1. Click Gradle menu on the right side of your ANDROID STUDIO IDE
2. Expand Tasks tree
3. Clink on signingReport

You will be able to see the signature at the bottom of IDE

Comment: How is your answer different than those provided?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/38369406/2308683

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 onward - new IntelliJ UI:

1. Open Execute Gradle Task
   [image]
2. Run the command `gradle signingReport`
   [image]
3. Inspect run
   [image]