# Issue getting Google Play Games API to work on non-release (debug) keys

Tags: google-play, google-play-services, google-play-games, google-api-console

For some reason, I am unable to get my app that I am developing with Google Play Games APIs to connect when I build an APK with the standard debug key fingerprint.  The only one that works is the release key that I created; so if I want to build a working version of the app, I must Export a Signed Application Package from Eclipse.

I've tried to add the additional debug SHAs to the Google Play dashboard, but when I enter the package name (the same one as the release version), it doesn't let me add another SHA1.  If I add the SHA1's to Google Cloud Console, it doesn't change anything; the Google+/Maps/Games APIs in my app won't connect.

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

This is the way I do it:

1. In the Develop Console, click the "Game Services" tab.
2. Select your game.
3. Select #2: "Linked Apps" and click the "Link Another App" button.
4. Enter name of app and package name (they can be the same as your release version).
5. Click the "Save and Continue" button.
6. Click "Authorize your app now".
7. Enter App details, including SHA1 of the debug version.
   ([This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727912/android-how-to-get-sha1-certificate-fingerprint) SO answer shows how to get this SHA1).

Comment: Here's the problem - when I try to Link Another App - it doesn't ask for the SHA1.  If I enter the package name, it just goes to the final step, and say it's been added, and it shows up in the list.  But I had no change to input the proper SHA1, so I have to go back to Cloud Console, add another app with a fake SHA1, then change its Android key to the one I need...it's a mess.  And that doesn't seem to work reliably, probably because it's wrong...

Comment: After you select "Link another app", in the "Link An Android App" section, at the top, there should be a blue "Save and continue" button (or just "continue" if you are returning to this page). This button should lead you to the SHA page. Don't you see this button?

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately i can't comment, this is an answer to the comment of @dcarr622 on the message of @tnbit

1. In the Develop Console, click the "Game Services" tab.
2. Select your game.
3. Select #2: "Linked Apps" and click the "Link Another App" button.
4. Enter name of app and package name (they can be the same as your release version).
5. Click the "Save and Continue" button.
6. Click "Authorize your app now".
7. Enter App details, including SHA1 of the debug version. (This SO answer shows how to get [this SHA1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727912/android-how-to-get-sha1-certificate-fingerprint)).

If you're not asked for the SHA go to the developer console and delete your existing credentials. They will be generated by the after step 7.

The last step solved all my issues and i had really hard time to find it, as it seems credentials can be added in the developer console as well which has not worked for me!

Following the described steps should get you going!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It seems that playstore keeps track of older sha1 too even if you delete the application. So simply let the non-working linked app be there and add another linked app. Probably the 3rd linked app would work.

In my case I had added release key sha and debug key sha initially. Then right before publishing I removed debug key sha. Then once my application got published I went back to debug key and then I could not add the debug key sha. But after adding 3rd linked app I could see the "authorize my app" option again.