# app-release-unsigned.apk is not signed

Tags: android, github, android-studio, digital-signature

I downloaded the zip file of an Android app on github and I'm trying to run it, but I get a dialog with this message

```
app-release-unsigned.apk is not signed. Please configure the signing information for the selected flavor using the Project Structure dialog.
```

I'm using Android Studio.
What am I supposed to do?

Comment: Although answers are pretty much given, but, just so that anyone still has issues, in my case, problem was due to the parent folder having a "space" in its name. So, it was "Android App", I changed it to "Android-App" , restarted the project and it worked

Comment: The "signing" process for Android is just painful. Epic fail on the Joel Test for "Can you do a build in ONE step"

Answer (score 496):

If anyone wants to debug **release** build using Android Studio, follow these steps:

1. Set build variant to release mode.

[image]

2. Right click on **app** in left navigation pane, click **Open Module Settings**.
3. Go to Signing Tab. Add a signing config and fill in information. Select your keychain as well.

[image]

4. Go to **Build Type** tab. Select release mode and set:

-Debuggable to *true*.

-Signing Config to the *config*. (The one you just created).

[image]

Sync your gradle. Enjoy!

Comment: Should we set Debuggable to false when actually generating the release APK for prod? or will studio do that on its own?

Comment: @IshaanGarg You should set debuggable to false while making release apk

Comment: You would think it would default to the first one created wonder why it does not... maybe it would be bad for some to sign packages they did not want to sign... but thanks, man I forgot to set the build type "Signing Config" and until the screenshot, I wasn't remembering

Comment: there is **NO NEED** to set ***Debuggable*** to ***true***, (unless really intended so).

Comment: You should be aware though that after setting a config to the build type, all your keys information (including the passwords) will appear in the gradle file...

Comment: There's an issue with changing signing configs via the Android Studio UI. Or that's what I find. AS updates the gradle.build file, deleting some of the dependencies (which were manually added to gradle.build). If AS shows an error after you update the signing configs, just compare your build.gradle with the previous one in local history.

Comment: For the last image it helps me to give SHA1 key for release mode.

 Multiple solution for one comment. thanks

Comment: "2- Right click on app in left navigation pane, click Open Module Settings."
IS NOT WORKING, In case some one facing the same problem you can select "file" -> "Project structure" OR  press "Ctrl + Alt + Shift + S"

Comment: it didn't work now it give me the following error : Failed to read key keyAlias from store

Comment: @has19 Which AS version are you using ?

Comment: @NightFury version 3.1.2

Comment: It gave me an error "could not get unknown property ....." to fix it, I just added `signingConfigs.` in front of the signing config name in build.gradle, e.g. in this example it would be `signingConfig signingConfigs.config`

Answer (score 102):

Make sure the *build variant* is set to *debug* (and not *release*) in Android Studio (check the *build variants* panel).

If set to debug, it should automatically sign the app with the auto-generated debug keystore, without editing the build scripts.

However you will need to create and configure a specific keystore for release.

Official documentation, covering debug and release modes: https://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Answer (score 66):

Always sign your build using your build.gradle DSL script like this:

```
    android {
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file("debug.keystore")
        }

        myConfig {
            storeFile file("other.keystore")
            storePassword "android"
            keyAlias "androidotherkey"
            keyPassword "android"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        bar {
            debuggable true
            jniDebugBuild true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        foo {
            debuggable false
            jniDebugBuild false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.myConfig
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to understand a little more of the Gradle build system associated to Android Studio just pay a visit to:

[Gradle Plugin User Guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide)

Comment: But why have I to do that? On the guide they say "By default, there is a debug configuration that is setup to use a debug keystore, with a known password and a default key with a known password.". I don't have any problems with other applications.

Comment: If your password is ok and debug.keystore is reachable, I don't know. The usual problems I saw in the past with this are file permission or directory permissions. Maybe the project you downloaded is keeping Android Studio local files which points to other debug keystore than yours. In any case your Gradle log must show the path error, please include that log for more help.

Comment: Hmmm, doesn't work for me either.  No gradle errors, but still getting the signing error (and it is pointed at my keyfile).

Comment: Hi Brian! Could you try to delete your debug.keystore? Then start a new dummy project and a new keystore must to be generated. After that, reopen your actual project and try. It is the only thing I can recommend if anything else commented before fails.

Comment: Isn't `debug.keystore` located in `.android` folder? You might want to give full path unless you moved it into your project

Answer (score 55):

If anyone wants to debug and release separate build variant using Android Studio 3.5, follow the below steps:
1. Set build variant to release mode.

[image: Build Variant]

2. Go to File >> Project Structure
3. Select Modules, then Signing Config
4. Click in the Plus icon under Signing Config

[image: Signing Config]

5. Select release section and Provide your release App Information then Apply and OK.

[image: signin]

6. Go to your app level `build.gradle` and change your `buildTypes` > "release" section like below Screenshot.

[image: final]

Then Run your Project. Happy Coding.

Comment: Where do you get the .jks file from?

Comment: @MarcAlexander here is no any .jks code generate Screenshot. You can generate .jks file from Android studio editor.

Comment: Step 6 could be done in Project Structure too. Project structure -> build variants -> Modules (app) -> Signing config. (Acording to NightFurrys [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34964168/9317258))

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for the SHA-256 key for the release variant so I can add it to Firebase Console. After following the steps I was able to get the SHA-256 and SAH-1 keys for release. Before i was getting none.

Answer (score 38):

I was successfully able to debug signed APK , Follow this procedure:-

1. Choose "release" version in "Build Variant" ToolBar
2. In the `Build.gradle` for the module set `debuggable true` for release build type
3. Go to File->Project Structure->under signing tab fill all info->Under Flavours 
   tab->Choose signing Config You just created
4. Set the breakpoints
5. Run the application in the debug mode

Comment: Not working for me. I have set debuggable true for staging variant but still, needs to sign the apk before building.

Answer (score 19):

For gradle Kotlin dsl

```
signingConfigs {
    create("releaseConfig") {
        storeFile = file("your keystore file path")
        storePassword = "storePassword"
        keyAlias = "keyAlias"
        keyPassword = "keyPassword"
    }
}
buildTypes {
    getByName("release") {
        signingConfig = signingConfigs.getByName("releaseConfig")
        isMinifyEnabled = true
        isShrinkResources = true
        proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16):

signingConfigs  should be before  buildTypes

```
signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file("debug.keystore")
        }

        myConfig {
            storeFile file("other.keystore")
            storePassword "android"
            keyAlias "androidotherkey"
            keyPassword "android"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        bar {
            debuggable true
            jniDebugBuild true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        foo {
            debuggable false
            jniDebugBuild false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.myConfig
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 14):

if you want to run app in **debug** mode

1) Look at Left Side bottom, above Favorites there is **Build Variants**

2) Click on Build Variants. Click on release and choose **debug**

it works perfect !!!

Answer (score 11):

The app project you downloaded may include a signed info in the file of build.gradle. If you saw codes like these:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

you could delete them and try again.

Answer (score 11):

My problem was solved by changing the build variant as suggested by Stéphane , if anyone was struggling to find the "Build variants" as I did here is a screenshot where you can find it .

[image]

Comment: I am facing problems after change build variant from Debug to Release

Answer (score 7):

For security reasons, you cannot install an unsigned apk on Android. So if you only have the unsigned apk: you must sign it. Here is how to do that : [link](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)

Note that you can sign the apk with a self-signed certificate.

An alternative can be either :

- to download the signed apk if available.
- to download the sources, compile them (with Android-Studio or gradle or ...). It will  produce multiple apks and one of them will be signed with your debug-key (and so you will be able to install it)

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding. I downloaded the zip of the code of the app and I'm trying to compile it with Android Studio...

Comment: so you must compile a signed version. Usually the signed version is build at the same time and is located in the same directory as the unsigned one.

Comment: If I generate a signed apk it works, but I can't do it every time I have to test the app. I'm missing something here, I just want to try the app as I do with my own applications...

Answer (score 4):

**How i solved this**

This error occurs because you have set your build variants to release mode. set it to build mode and run project again.

If you want to run in release mode, just generate a signed apk the way we do it normally when releasing the app

Comment: I only have "debug" and "release" options?

Answer (score 2):

In  tool window bar select Build Variants 
Change Build Variant from Release to Debug

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to change the name of my signing config from the default "config" to "debug". To verify, I changed it to some other random name and got the error again, and then changed it back to "debug" and the error was gone. So while it seems artificial and I tend to not believe this is the whole story, give this solution a try.

Answer (score 0):

i also appear this problem,and my code below

```
        storeFile file(properties.getProperty("filepath"))
        storePassword properties.getProperty("keypassword")
        keyAlias properties.getProperty("keyAlias")
        keyPassword properties.getProperty("keypassword")
```

the reason is property name error,it should be keyPassword not keypassword

Answer (score 0):

What finally worked for me, and I have no idea why, is:

- Went to LastPass (the service I use to keep all my passwords)
- Select my password by putting the cursor on top of the password and double clicking
- Once selected I press cmd C to copy
- Went to Android study and cmd V to paste

Notice I did try to copy many times by selecting the password by clicking at the end of the password and selecting the password by moving the mouse.

It is strange but it only worked by double clicking on top of the password to copy it.

Also I did use the Open Module Settings > Signing... method explained by @NightFury on this post.

Answer (score -1):

adding below lines of code in build.gradel file worked for me, add them under buildTypes block below release as shown

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        debuggable true
    }
```