# Enable LogCat on Release Build in Android Studio

Tags: android, logcat

By default, when I change `Build Variants` to `release` I don't get any Logs on the logcat, but I do need to read release logs of my app, how can I enable this?

Comment: Change your log level. I may be wrong but as I understand it `Log.d` calls are removed when a release version is exported - I'm not sure what other levels (if any) are also removed.

Comment: @Squonk I have also recently observed that Log.v logs are also not exposed in release build. Do any one know what can be the reason for it?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Add `android:debuggable="true"` (default is false) to your Manifest inside the `<application>` tag.

[From the docs:](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html)

> android:debuggable
>   Whether or not the application can be debugged,
>   even when running on a device in user mode — "true" if it can be, and
>   "false" if not.

[respectively](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/preparing.html#publishing-configure)

> You can disable debugging by removing the android:debuggable attribute
>   from the  tag in your manifest file, or by setting the
>   android:debuggable attribute to false in your manifest file.

#### Edit

You may need to add the following to your `build.gradle` file inside the android{...} tag:

```
lintOptions {
   checkReleaseBuilds false
}
```

And **as a side-note**: Right on the device the Logs are always written, no matter if your application's *debuggable* is set to *false* or *true*. But via the **LogCat** in Android Studio it's only possible if debuggable is set to true. (Just tested this)

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct. At least, the docs it cites don't say that turning on `android:debuggable` will turn on logging. In fact, https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/preparing.html#publishing-configure is fairly clear that turning off logging and turning off debugging are two separate things. The OP asked how to turn on logging.

Comment: P.S. Please correct me if I'm wrong, citing a source that says that `android:debuggable="true"` enables logging.

Comment: You're somewhat right, but `debuggable` means that the Android Monitor in Android Studio can be attached to the currently running APK. This enables the Logcat to show the log statements like in debug builds. Other than that: This answer is now a little bit over three years old - so most probably you should switch to the corresponding `build.gradle` property called `debuggable` which can be set depending on the buildType.

Answer (score 44):

You should add

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable true
```

In this case you can use `Log.` or `System.out.println` and see logs.

If you cannot run release version (`app` is disabled), and error is shown: "apk is not signed. Please configure the signing information for the selected flavor using the Project Structure dialog", see [app-release-unsigned.apk is not signed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25001479/app-release-unsigned-apk-is-not-signed).

Comment: This works for me. Having logs in release build is necessary at lease after enabling proguard for the first time. But don't forget to make `debuggable false` for production builds :)

Comment: @MohK, agree with you. Strange, but in another project I have `debuggable false` in `release` build, but see logs and debugging does not work even in `true` state. :)

Comment: It seems it only works with System.out.println() in the new versions of AS.

Comment: @IldiX, did you also try Kotlin `println()` or `Timber.`?

Comment: @CoolMind the project is in java.

Comment: @IldiX, I have `debuggable false` in `release` build (`minifyEnabled true`, `shrinkResources true`), but `Log.d()` works. AS 3.6.1.

Comment: @thecr0w, glad to hear it! Good luck!

Answer (score 34):

I do not like the other solution because then you are not testing how the App really is deployed.

A better solution is to open the [Android Device Monitor](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/monitor.html) where you can see the logs even when in release configuration with `debuggable=false`.

Find it here:

> Tools -> Android -> Android Device Monitor

**Update:**
Android Device Monitor was removed in Android Studio 3.2. However, it is still present in SDK, and you can use it to see the logs (it is located in `$ANDROID_SDK/tools/`)

Comment: http://joxi.ru/eAOl5EWu8Ll5ro
App from market with debuggable not mentioned in manifest (thus, it's false). Nothing - in AS LogCat or in DeviceMonitor

Comment: you will not see Log.v and Log.d this way

Comment: @DenRimus, in Play Market, I think, an application should be in release mode. So, there can be turned off all logs.

Comment: You won't be able to filter this way because you can't see which log corresponds to your package.

Comment: @JensV you could still filter by your package name, right?

Comment: @IHC_Applroid No, if the App isn't set as debuggable, you will only see the pid, tag, level and message.

Comment: Note too that in ADM LogCat window, you also can't filter on tags *by typing in the live filter field.* That field seems to filter only on message text. Instead, you can add saved filters to filter by tag.

Comment: Android Device Monitor was removed in AS 3.2 - https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/monitor
However, it is still present in SDK, and you can use it to see the logs (it is located in `$ANDROID_SKD/tools/`)

Comment: You can also use 3rd party app like [Facebook Flipper](https://fbflipper.com/) to get the logs even in release version.

Comment: There's a typo: should be `$ANDROID_SDK/tools/` instead of `$ANDROID_SKD/tools/` - unfortunately I cannot save my edit

Answer (score 5):

This approach will obviously help you to get logs while testing the production build. But be careful while uploading your app to Google Play Store, Toggle **`debuggable`** to **`false`** before uploading to production.

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        manifestPlaceholders = [crashlyticsCollectionEnabled: "false"]
    }
    release {
        manifestPlaceholders = [crashlyticsCollectionEnabled: "false"]
        lintOptions {
            checkReleaseBuilds false
            abortOnError false
        }
        shrinkResources true
        minifyEnabled true
        debuggable true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.productionrelease
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

set **`crashlyticsCollectionEnabled`** to **`false`** to avoid your crashes to report to Google Play-Store while debugging.

Answer (score 3):

`debuggable true` in `build.gradle` works well, except that `BuildConfig.DEBUG` is also going to be true. This might be a problem if your app relies on `BuildConfig.DEBUG` to do something only when it's a debug build.

In such a case, try `Log.wtf(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, "something went wrong")`, which will print to logcat even if it's a release build.

Comment: Agree with you. In this case I added a constant in a config class for test and release builds (and didn't rely on `BuildConfig.DEBUG`). For instance `const val TEST = true`. But don't forget to change it's value when publish an application.

Comment: Log.wtf is super helpful

Answer (score 3):

remove "package:mine" in filter field of logcat

[image]