# crashed when install signed apk in android react-native

Tags: react-native

In local mode apk install and run properly but when generated signed apk and then install in real device its crashed in react-native how to solve this error

In local mode apk install and run properly but when generated signed apk and then install in real device its crashed in react-native how to solve this error

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25610936/enable-logcat-on-release-build-in-android-studio and find the issue that cause the crash from log and update the question

Answer (score 0):

You need to log the error first to be able to fix it

i suggest you to use [react-native-exception-handler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-exception-handler) library to catch the error In **Bundled mode**.

Comment: thankyou but it is not working for me. only generate signed apk and then install in real device application is crashed

Comment: Did the app crash before showing the splash screen?

Comment: error :-  big size of image in home screen so that application crashed....
thankyou brother for support!