# Specific activity not showing after getting specific Firebase notifications in signed APK

Tags: android, firebase, android-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I'm not able to open specific activities via specific Notification in my signed APK. It works perfectly when we run app from PC in Android Studio.

This is what I can achieve on Android Studio:

Send the push notification via Firebase Console, then if it contains a specific key-value pair (e.g. `timetable`, `engineering`), then Timetable activity opens.

This works fine on Android Studio, but not in debuggable and release signed APK.

In deuggable and signed APK, the main activity opens every time  when we send specified key-value pairs like `timetable` as key and `engineering` as value.

Following code is not executing in signed and debuggable apk. MainActivity Code:

```
if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {

        for (String key : getIntent().getExtras().keySet()) {
            String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString(key);

            if (key.equals("timetable") && value.equals("engineering")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, Timetable.class);
                intent.putExtra("value", value);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
            else if(key.equals("timetable") && value.equals("science")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, Timetable.class);
                intent.putExtra("value", value);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
            else if (key.equals("timetable") && value.equals("law")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, Timetable.class);
                intent.putExtra("value", value);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
            else if (key.equals("timetable") && value.equals("management")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, Timetable.class);
                intent.putExtra("value", value);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
            else if (key.equals("timetable") && value.equals("pharmacy")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, Timetable.class);
                intent.putExtra("value", value);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
            else if (key.equals("timetable") && value.equals("mmss")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, Timetable.class);
                intent.putExtra("value", value);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
            else if (key.equals("timetable") && value.equals("commerce")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, Timetable.class);
                intent.putExtra("value", value);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
            else if (key.equals("timetable") && value.equals("education")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, Timetable.class);
                intent.putExtra("value", value);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
            else if (key.equals("result") && value.equals("rengineering")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, Results.class);
                intent.putExtra("value", value);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
            else if (key.equals("result") && value.equals("rscience")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, Results.class);
                intent.putExtra("value", value);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }

            else if (key.equals("result") && value.equals("rarts")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, Results.class);
                intent.putExtra("value", value);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }

            else if (key.equals("result") && value.equals("rlaw")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, Results.class);
                intent.putExtra("value", value);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }

            else if (key.equals("result") && value.equals("rmanagement")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, Results.class);
                intent.putExtra("value", value);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }

            else if (key.equals("result") && value.equals("rpharmacy")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, Results.class);
                intent.putExtra("value", value);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }

            else if (key.equals("result") && value.equals("rmmss")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, Results.class);
                intent.putExtra("value", value);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }

            else if (key.equals("result") && value.equals("rcommerce")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, Results.class);
                intent.putExtra("value", value);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }

            else if (key.equals("result") && value.equals("reducation")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, Results.class);
                intent.putExtra("value", value);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }


        }
    }
```

FirebaseMessagingService Class

```
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
            Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
    }

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    //The message which i send will have keys named [message, image, AnotherActivity] and corresponding values.
    //You can change as per the requirement.

    //message will contain the Push Message
    String message = remoteMessage.getData().get("message");

    //String imageUri = remoteMessage.getData().get("image");
    //If the key AnotherActivity has  value as True then when the user taps on notification, in the app AnotherActivity will be opened.
    //If the key AnotherActivity has  value as False then when the user taps on notification, in the app MainActivity will be opened.
    String TrueOrFlase = remoteMessage.getData().get("AnotherActivity");

    //To get a Bitmap image from the URL received
    sendNotification(message, bitmap, TrueOrFlase);

}


/**
 * Create and show a simple notification containing the received FCM message.
 */

private void sendNotification(String messageBody, Bitmap image, String TrueOrFalse) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.putExtra("AnotherActivity", TrueOrFalse);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setLargeIcon(image)/*Notification icon image*/
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setContentTitle(messageBody)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                    .bigPicture(image))/*Notification with Image*/
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}

/*
*To get a Bitmap image from the URL received
* */

}
```

Comment: I couldn't see you are passing any intent extra with key "timetable" or ""result". In your sendNotification method you are adding only "AnotherActivity".

Comment: *This works fine on studio but not in debuggable and release signed apk.* I didn't understand what you mean by this..

Comment: hm. Its working in studio. What should I change?

Comment: This works in studio means when we connect mobile via USB and run the app directly from studio. But when we generate signed apk, and install that on device, it doesn't work.

Comment: I think its related to debug configuration. Do I need to edit SHA1 value and put it of release configuration?

Comment: Finally, I got it working! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25001479/app-release-unsigned-apk-is-not-signed/34964168#34964168