# I'm trying to generate a release sha1 certificate fingerprint with these line of code

Tags: android

keytool -list -v -keystore D:\Projects\TheWallApplication\TheWall KeyStorepoint\TheWallKeystore.jks -alias key0

but getting :-
Illegal option:  KeyStorepoint\TheWallKeystore.jks
keytool -list [OPTION]...

Answer (score 2):

**Easiest way for getting SHA1 Key in android studio both (Debug and release Mode)**

1. Open `Android Studio`
2. Open Your Project
3. Click on **Gradle** (From **Right Side Panel**, you will see **Gradle Bar**)
4. Click on **Refresh** (Click on Refresh from Gradle Bar , you will see List Gradle scripts of your Project)
5. Click on Your Project (Your Project Name form List)
6. Click on Tasks/Android
7. Double Click on `signingReport` (You will get `SHA1` and `MD5` in Run Bar)

**If you are using new Android Studio it shows time to execute on top there is Toggle task execution mode click on that you will get you SHA-1 key. Check 2nd and 3rd reference images.**

[image: Check image for details]
[image][image]

**Generate SHA-1 for Release Mode**

1-First add keystore config in your gradle [How to add config in gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25001479/app-release-unsigned-apk-is-not-signed/34964168#34964168).

2-After Adding Config in gradle change build variant. [image]

3-Then Follow Above Procedure you will get SHA-1 for release mode.

4-Check Image. [image]

ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35308827/13564911

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio of version 4.2  and greater,  the above answer doesn't work. So for Android Studio 4.2, follow these steps given in this answer.

***Link***:- [How to get the SHA-1 fingerprint certificate in Android Studio for debug mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27609442/how-to-get-the-sha-1-fingerprint-certificate-in-android-studio-for-debug-mode/67866731#67866731)