# Google Maps Android API v2 with blank map displayed, on android studio

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to use Google Maps Android API v2 in my android app but the result is a blank (gray) map displayed with button of zoom
i tried many tutorial but the result is the same.
Android studio, unix

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.app.Authentification"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" ></activity>



    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />


    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value=" My key " />



    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <activity android:name=".Send_remarquesSugges" ></activity>
    <activity android:name=".SendMailActivity" ></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Menu_Genaral" ></activity>
    <activity android:name=".AddChantier" ></activity>
    <activity android:name=".AddZone" ></activity>
    <activity android:name=".AddProjet" ></activity>
    <activity android:name=".AddProspect" ></activity>
    <activity android:name=".activity_Commercial" ></activity>
    <activity android:name=".AddClient" ></activity>
    <activity android:name=".AddSuiviChantier" ></activity>
    <activity android:name=".AddCommercial" ></activity>
    <activity android:name=".daoServer.Activity_add_chantier" ></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Menu_Visite" ></activity>
    <activity android:name=".AddReclamationn" ></activity>
    <activity android:name=".add_projet3" ></activity>
    <activity android:name=".AddRecouvrement" ></activity>
    <activity android:name=".AddRetourrs" ></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Cartographie" ></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Affectation" ></activity>
    <activity android:name=".ActivityRendezVous" ></activity>
    <activity android:name=".contacts" ></activity>
    <activity android:name=".AddRendezvous" ></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Add_RD" ></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Menu_RD" ></activity>
    <activity android:name=".AddCmd3" ></activity>
    <activity android:name=".menu_contact" ></activity>
    <activity android:name=".AddContact" ></activity>
    <activity android:name=".AddSuiviProspect" ></activity>
    <activity android:name=".menu_type_cmde" ></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Add_Articles" ></activity>
    <activity android:name=".menu_parametre" ></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Menu_GenaralAdmin" ></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Cartographie_2" ></activity>

    <activity android:name=".mainnActi_Rendez_vous" ></activity>
    <activity android:name=".AddCmd_Tele" ></activity>
    <activity android:name=".AddCam" ></activity>
    <activity android:name=".menu_projet3" ></activity>
    <activity android:name=".AddVisite2__" ></activity>
    <activity android:name=".mainnActi_client" ></activity>
    <activity android:name=".AddCmd2" ></activity>

</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

My build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'
}
```

Thanks for your help.

i tried many tutorail like this one http://glennsayers.com/android-mapping/
i cant post image the result is the same of this link with google writed in down of page http://android-er.blogspot.fr/2012/12/google-maps-android-api-v2-with-blank.html

Comment: Did you set your api key?

Comment: in the device :s, yes the api key is correct i tried to creeate a new project with one activity who display the map with new key but the same result, blank page whith zoom button.

Answer (score 2):

```
 <uses-permission android:name="your.package.name.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
```

this permission is missing.

Comment: i add this permission but the result is the same :s

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using android studio. The official documentation says that you have to get your `sha1` key from `debug.keystore` but that is not true at all. You have to use the `sha1` key from your `.jks` file.

I´m not sure how to get this but I found it using eclipse. You choose any project and when you export a project you choose your key. In the end of the process you see your `sha1`, this is the real certificate and it's different than in `debug.keystore`.

See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26895345/4987172) for reference.