# Android app does not work when I add my google play account

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I have a android map application .  When I compile my application on the phone running smoothly and Map opens and shows my location.but When I install my application google play and dnowload my mobile phone android app get location but don't show map.
Finaly ı am sorry for my english.

Comment: You need to upload the signed apk to google play

Comment: there might be the problem with signing, you need to add your keystore SHA to you maps api key since the debug signing you have been using for testing is different then release signing with your keystore

Answer (score 1):

When you run your app directly from Eclipse or Android studio, debug key is used.
So when you publish your app to Google Play, you have to add your SHA1 key to Google Play Console.
You can [find how to get SHA1 here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727912/sha-1-fingerprint-of-keystore-certificate).

Updated:
Please follow [this documen](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start)

Scroll down on the page and follow "Create an API project in the Google APIs Console" and "Obtain a Google Maps API key"

Comment: thank you for answer.I use eclipse and ı get google-map-api V2 key with my SHA1 but ı didn't add google play console.How can ı do it?

Comment: i think what he was trying to say was that you just need to add SHA1 of your keystore to you existing google-map-api V2 key

Comment: ı try all answer but didn't work.I think mistake is create release key.If we install  application google play  we need to do anything extra.

Comment: Yes, if you publish your app to Google Play, you have to add your SHA1 key on Google APIs Console. This SHA1 key is NOT debug SHA1 key.