# Google Maps V2 not working in production with correct key

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm having major troubles getting Google Maps working in production within an Android app. This is what I am currently getting (the bottom is just ads).

[image: App production screen]

Key Steps I have followed:

1) I have ensured I have got the correct SHA1 Production Key and have implemented it on the Google Console API as well as within the app (They key that google gives). I have registered two keys - one for the debug and one for production

2) Internet, location, etc is working

3) The app works in DEBUG mode, but does not work when signed and installed on device via USB. I have triple checked the SHA 1 signature of the sign, etc.

4) The MapsFragment comes from the template available in Android Studio.

In production mode, the log cat displays this:

```
01-11 16:04:54.511  19346-19437/com.mike.mapstest E/Google Maps Android API﹕ Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start for how to correctly set up the map.
01-11 16:04:54.516  19346-19437/com.mike.mapstest E/Google Maps Android API﹕ In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
    Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
    Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
    API Key: YOUR_KEY_HERE
    Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>): <SHA1 Removed for this> ;com.mike.mapstest
```

This error obviously says something is wrong with my auth? 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: check your SHA1 is correct for release mode?

Comment: @MohammodHossain, Yes, I am using the SHA key that you get from signing the app for production.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Based on the logcat output from your debuggable release build:

```
01-11 16:04:54.511  19346-19437/com.mike.mapstest E/Google Maps Android API﹕ Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start for how to correctly set up the map.
01-11 16:04:54.516  19346-19437/com.mike.mapstest E/Google Maps Android API﹕ In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
    Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
    Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
    API Key: YOUR_KEY_HERE
    Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>): <SHA1 Removed for this> ;com.mike.mapstest
```

it would appear that you have not overridden the api key placeholder `YOUR_KEY_HERE` in the manifest (or separate api keys file, depending on your configuration). Replace that string, wherever it lives, with your actual key and you should be good to go.

Edit: [this tutorial](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_the_Google_Maps_Android_API_in_Android_Studio), if it matches your configuration, probably explains why you are only seeing this for release builds:

> Return to Android Studio and paste the API key into the YOUR_KEY_HERE section of the file:
>
> Note that these steps have enabled Google Maps support for the debug version of the application package. The API key will also need to be added to the google_maps_api.xml file located in MapDemo -> app -> src -> release -> res -> values when the release version of the application is ready to be built.

Comment: Thanks @stkent. This was the issue. It appears one must hardcode the API key into the manifest rather than using a string resource from an external XML file.

Comment: Exact same problem and this was the fix. I will repeat: you MUST hardcode the API key in the manifest!

Comment: @ForeverLearning  I am having the same problem, but still after hardcoding in manifest, no luck :(

Comment: Same issu here, but no hardcoding solve it. Nevertheless, when I'm writing this comment, there is NO "Google Maps Android API v2" on Google Console, just "Google Maps Android API". Is it the same?

Comment: Ok, I've found the solutions. 
First: The key has to be hardcoded
Second: When I generated the KEY I used key;packagename template, what the Android studio generated to me on the comment section at google_maps_api.xml . Yeah... THE PACKAGE NAME BELONGS TO THE FRAGMENT, AND NOT THE MAINFEST PACKAGE. This killed everything, when I switch it with the one from the manifest, it was OK. Make sure you using the key;manifestpackage template on the GoogleConsole when generating your API key @DroidWormNarendra

Comment: For some reason, generating the API Key from the link provided in the comments doesn't work (well, didn't for me). Instead, generating the key from [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup) did. Just follow the instructions and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 12):

I was having these same issues, and was banging my head against the wall for a few days. I read all the posts about putting the correct key in place. I kept putting the correct key in my google_maps_api.xml file. StKent above mentioned to make sure to overwrite with the actual string in AndroidManifest.xml. This is what fixed it for me.

**What I had when it didn't work:**
in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

and in google_maps_api.xml:

```
 <string name="google_maps_key"
        templateMergeStrategy="preserve"
        translatable="false">AIza_the actual key</string>
```

**What I changed to for it to work**
I changed my AndroidManifest.xml to include:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzsa_the actual key" />
```

Comment: Yeah, @StKent was the right answer, need to hardcode it. Caused me so much frustration when I did it following the actual proper documentation.

Comment: I hardcoded debug API_KEY for tag com.google.android.geo.API_KEY in manifest.xml, but still its not working.
FYI it was working properly yesterday, but suddenly stopped showing up map layer, showing just Google icon in bottom|left

Comment: this solution worked in 2022!

Answer (score 4):

debug and  production key will be different . If you use debug key for release mode ,you can not view the google map. For release mode , when you change google map key , you should clean the project then export apk.

you can get more information 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

to get private SHA1 from debug key store

keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass your_app_password

to see more

[SHA-1 fingerprint of keystore certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727912/sha-1-fingerprint-of-keystore-certificate)

or you can you eclipse tool to generate private SHA1 key using export menu

Comment: I am using the SHA key found when signing the app for release through the keystore

Comment: ok. change your SHA1 key as public debug key, then see your google map.

Comment: public debug key? Is this the key that the IDE generates? The app works when using a debug key in debug mode.

Comment: I have signed the app with the key but in debug mode (instead of release). This generates the "app-debug.apk" file in AS. This apk does work.

Comment: for releage mode you need private map api key. to do this you should the following steps. create debug key store then SHA1 then google map api key

Comment: Are you saying that we should enter the _debug_ keystore's SHA-1 hash into Google Developer Console?  If so, why would we not use the release keystore?

Answer (score 4):

When using Android Studio to generate the Google Maps Activity, it will ignore your gradle build configs and use the default `debug.keystore`. The SHA1 in `google_maps_api.xml` is based off of this default. When creating permission in the Google API console, make sure to use your production and debug SHA1 if you are using the non default.

Comment: Good to know! I have not used the Android Studio maps activity generator yet.

Comment: The language of your answer is somewhat unclear.  Which keystore should be used to generate the SHA-1 hash to be entered into the Google console?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen this was from many versions ago so it might no longer be valid; however, when using Android Studio's function to generate the Google Maps Activity, it would never use your production configuration.

In Google console, if you are setting it up for production you should use the SHA1 for production keystore. I'm suggesting your Google console should have both debug AND production so your test builds work.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had entered the wrong package name in Google API's API Manager - Credentials - "Restrict usage to your Android apps". Make sure you enter the correct package name (as in AndroidManifest.xml) and the correct SHA fingerprints (for debug and production). [image: Google API Manager Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I put on the Manifest the "Key for browser apps (with referers)" instead of the "Key for Android apps (with certificates)" from the Google API Console

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the gray screen was caused by having a custom implementation of `HostnameVerifier` that was preventing the tiles from being loaded.

Hope this will help someone else in the future.

Answer (score -1):

error //Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled. 
In this u can't find like Google Maps Android API v2 in Google Cloud Platform Console.[in this, give the exact Package Name: and signature of your project which is showing in run window or debug window , I faced the same problem because of changing MapActivity package location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVeYQ.jpg)
I struggled to find this whole day so make sure whether u changed any packages inside project if so give package which is showing in error text
*emphasized text*
 Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
    API Key: YOUR_KEY_HERE
    Android Application (;):  ;***com.mike.mapstest***