# google map android error

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

I saw many question is similar to me

> Google Maps Android API: In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
>                                                                                     Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.                                                                            Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
>                                                                                       API Key: ###############################
>                                                                                       Android Application (;): #######################################################;

but not working

Comment: https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/issues/69

Comment: Possible Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27883587/google-maps-v2-not-working-in-production-with-correct-key

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Maps V2 not working in production with correct key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27883587/google-maps-v2-not-working-in-production-with-correct-key)

Answer (score 1):

this problem is due to disable api. You need to enable **Google Map API** from **[Google API Manager](https://console.developers.google.com)** and then follow these steps to enable api.

**Steps**

1. Open your project dashboard and it will look like below image
   [image: Your project dashboard]
2. Click on **ENABLE API** button and you will get below screen with library of APIs that you can enable or disable

[image: API library]

3. Now select **Google Maps Android API** and you will get below screen
   [image: Enable or Disable API]

**If you get button DISABLE API means your APIs are enable or if you found ENABLE button that means your api is not enable yet**

Hope this will help you.