# Maps are not displayed when the application is published in the store

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

I am working with Google Maps only that I am having a problem when viewing the map in the application, I already generated the launch certificate and I provide my fingerprint, I generated the signed Apk to upload it to the store, nothing more that when published in the store the maps are no longer displayed but I test the other devices by passing the Apk file and it works wonders, I feel dismayed by the problem I am having, I need help in this.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<permission
    android:name="ixzihua.com.mx.ixzihua.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="ixzihua.com.mx.ixzihua.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />


<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27883587/google-maps-v2-not-working-in-production-with-correct-key

Comment: if your app is saying published in the console then wait for 24 hours. it will be listed.

Answer (score 0):

**Step by Step**

1. find your keystore (*.jks file) (you needed to generate this in order to publish anyway)
2. execute something like this in command prompt (Windows) "C:\Program Files\Java... whatever java version you have ...\jre\bin\keytool.exe" -list -v -keystore myappkeystore.jks
   You'll see a bunch of info including your release APK's SHA1 if done right.
3. Go here: https://code.google.com/apis/console
4. Opt out of the new interface (its horrible) and use the old interface if possible
5. In old interface go to services and make sure Google Maps is enabled
6. Now go to API Access and update your old SHA1 with the new one by click "Edit Allowed Android Apps" to the right and overwrite the old one with the new one. Click Update. Done.