# google map in fragment without api_key

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to implement a map in my application, but it's an internal prototype and I don't want to register it anywhere. [This tutorial](https://gist.github.com/joshdholtz/4522551) is such simple, but it needs an api key and I don't know where I can get it... .

In worst case it's enough to show a pin on a given gps position without searching for adresses (but sure, it would be better if I'm able to search for adresses...).

Comment: sorry, I needed some time ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API key is what identifies the mobile application and authorises it to access the services offered by Google. You are going to need this if you intend to implement the Google Maps API in your app.

First of all, you need to access the [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com)

You then need to search for the Google Android Maps API

Next, you need to get the SHA-1 certificate fingerprint from the App you have created. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727912/sha-1-fingerprint-of-keystore-certificate) will help you generate it.

Finally, you need to insert the key generated by Google in the manifest file of your app.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

For api key; you'll need to go to Google Developers Console.
There's no other way.
Follow the link for details:
 https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Answer (score 1):

You must register your app in order to use Google Maps (that's what the tutorial is using).

Check the [Google Maps Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/) for Android. [Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/signup#create_an_api_project_in_the_console_name) you have how to obtain an API key