# Map is not loading

Tags: android, google-maps

```
 <string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false">AIzaSyCxVL4qigDepaIfT9ZZMfT4eZr_PPri04s
    </string>
```

Here's the log cat:

```
12-23 12:11:31.091 15026-15026/? E/SELinux: [DEBUG] seapp_context_lookup: seinfoCategory = default
12-23 12:11:31.101 15026-15026/? E/SELinux: [DEBUG] seapp_context_lookup: seinfoCategory = default
12-23 12:11:31.561 15026-15062/com.example.hamees.hf_mainuserinterface E/GMPM: getGoogleAppId failed with status: 10
12-23 12:11:31.561 15026-15062/com.example.hamees.hf_mainuserinterface E/GMPM: Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
12-23 12:11:57.831 15026-15592/com.example.hamees.hf_mainuserinterface E/b: Authentication failed on the server.
12-23 12:11:57.831 15026-15592/com.example.hamees.hf_mainuserinterface E/Google Maps Android API: Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start for how to correctly set up the map.
12-23 12:11:57.831 15026-15592/com.example.hamees.hf_mainuserinterface E/Google Maps Android API: In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
                                                                                                  Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
                                                                                                  Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
                                                                                                    API Key: AIzaSyCxVL4qigDepaIfT9ZZMfT4eZr_PPri04s
                                                                                                    Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>): 44:56:1D:16:8F:1E:A8:6C:C3:1C:03:FC:8F:DA:2A:08:1C:48:E0:2D;com.example.hamees.hf_mainuserinterface
```

Comment: God, please edit your code next time man!

Comment: Have you enable Map Api v2 from google console and try to use map key with debug or release key store for load map.

Answer (score 2):

The logcat is giving you the EXACT reason of the loading fail:

```
Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.  

Ensure that the following Android Key exists:                                                     
API Key: AIzaSyCxVL4qigDepaIfT9ZZMfT4eZr_PPri04s       

Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>): 44:56:1D:16:8F:1E:A8:6C:C3:1C:03:FC:8F:DA:2A:08:1C:48:E0:2D;com.example.hamees.hf_mainuserinterface
```

The Api key you provided is not valid. Ensure that:

- Your key is activated, from the google server it can take up to several minuts
- You provide the good fingerprint SHA1 (one is for release, one for debug: [SHA-1 fingerprint of keystore certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727912/sha-1-fingerprint-of-keystore-certificate))
- Your app has the permissions and everything is set to use the google map API: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start?hl=en)