# Android Development - Google Play Services, Google Login Integration

Tags: android, google-play-services

I followed a couple of videos on youtube including the one from Google Developers, and the guide on google's developer website https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating .

My project-level dependency:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

My app-level dependency:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.0'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I've created a web-client and I've inserted the client id as a string into the **strings.xml** file.
I've created an Android client and checked twice that an email and name exist in the consent screen and that the SHA1 hash is correct.
I've pasted the .json file into the root of my app.
My app has the correct permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
```

I'm probably forgetting something, but the gist is, **isSuccess()** is returning false, so I logged the result and the result says

```
Status{statusCode=DEVELOPER_ERROR, resolution=null}
```

Any ideas would be great since I've been mirroring everything from the sample app Google provides for the google sign-in project.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting an error **`Status{statusCode=DEVELOPER_ERROR, resolution=null}`** maybe because your application is misconfigured. Check  your google api configuration. Make sure you have registered your debug and release SHA1 keys in the console.

Based on the walkthrough published in https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start:

> Probably you created the configuration file using the SHA1 of your "production" token, use the 'androiddebugkey' alias to gather the SHA1 corresponding to the debug version of your app and copy the configuration file to the 'app' directoy, you should have both configuration files (one for debug purposes and another for production environment).

Make sure your package name is  the one in your `build.gradle`, and its not being overriden in a build variant.

Check these threads:

- [Error: Status{statusCode=DEVELOPER_ERROR, resolution=null}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37273145/error-statusstatuscode-developer-error-resolution-null)
- [Google sign-in Android with Firebase - statusCode DEVELOPER_ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37376939/google-sign-in-android-with-firebase-statuscode-developer-error)