# google Plus Login Failed error code 17 android

Tags: android, authentication, oauth, google-plus

I am getting error of google Plus Login Failed error code 17 while using the release apk. In debug apk it is working. not able to figure it out the proper error and solution.Even error message is null.

```
 @Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Google plus login failed : onConnectionFailed");
    if (!mIntentInProgress && result.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            mIntentInProgress = true;
            mActivity.startIntentSenderForResult(result.getResolution()
                    .getIntentSender(), AUTH_CODE_REQUEST_CODE, null, 0, 0, 0);
        } catch (SendIntentException e) {
            mIntentInProgress = false;
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    } else {
        if (mGoogleLoginListener != null) // it goes here
            mGoogleLoginListener.googlePlusLoginFailed(result.getErrorCode());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found answer!

According to google document about  [Debug & release](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/signup) we have to generate both debug and release SHA-1 fingerprint using the keytool. I also found [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37447381/5059725).

- Make sure your package name is what you expect - e.g. its the one in
  your build.gradle, and its not being overriden in a build variant or
  product flavor.
- Make sure you have registered your debug and release    SHA1 keys in
  the console.

Steps followed by me:

**For debug SHA-1:**

keytool -list -v -keystore  -alias 
For Debug, replace with your debug.keystore path, for Example :

keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\Desktop.android\debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey

*Password*: android

***For Release SHA-1, replace with your keystore path and alias password, for Example :***

keytool -list -v -keystore C:\ProjectTest\keystore\my-release-key.jks -alias alias_name

*Password*: Your alias password.