# Getting error while Ionic Angularfire2 signin using Google

Tags: cordova, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3, angularfire2

I am trying google signin using AngularFire2. Google authentication is working perfectly when I use `this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup`. But `signInWithPopup` is only for browser and wont work for mobile app. As per google documentation, `signInWithRedirect` should be used for app. I tried using method but it is opening browser for signin.

Instead I tried using cordova google plus plugin to signin, and using the accessToken to authenticate Firebase.

When I try to call login method of cordova plugin, it is throwing error, and error has only '17' number.

I have following questions

- Is there anything I am missing?
- What is the better way to sign in ionic mobile app using google plus?
- what is the meaning of error '17'?

**Here is my code**

```
this.gPlus.login({
    webClientId: '<myClientID>',
    offline: true
  })
  .then(res => {
    this.afAuth.auth.signInWithCredential(res.accessToken);
  }, (err) => {

    console.log(err) // Logging 17 here.
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  })
```

Comment: Your scenario is right. But first, you should figure out the error come from which step. Cordova google login or firebase login?

Comment: @Duannx,  
It’s coming from cordova google login. I can catch it in catch method

Comment: Can you capture your error please? You do not need webClientId so just remove it. Try `this.gPlus.login({})`

Comment: @Duannx i tried passing empty object, its giving same error. And error has value 17

Comment: Maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40154894/google-plus-login-failed-error-code-17-android) could help

Answer (score 0):

```
let provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider).then(() => {
    firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then((result)=>{

    }).catch(function(error){

    }) 
})
```

Use this code for signin using google. It will surely open browser for signin but it can also have facility for getting you back to the desired page in application. You will get the data as well.