# Error with google sign in android

Tags: android, authentication, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-authenticator

I'm trying to authenticate users on an app using firebase and google sign in `Button`, but it gives me the following error:

> Status{statusCode=DEVELOPER_ERROR, resolution=null}

But I already have the google-service.json file because I used facebook's `Button` without problems. Therefore I don't know whats the problem with google's `Button`.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37447381/4815718

Answer (score 0):

In my experience The Google authentication process usually has these errors when the api credentials are not set up accurate. Make sure you have access clients containing your SHA-1 fingerprint for BOTH your debug and release keystore.
Make sure you add Google services sdk dependency in your build.Gradle and double check in your developer console if the corresponding api is enabled.
Refer this [document](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating)