# In my react native application I am having DEVELOPPER_ERROR when I use signin with google api along with firebase after building app-debug.apk

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am developping a react native application that uses firebase firestore and google authentication to sign in. When running in debug mode in the emulator everything works and I can authenticate using google auth's api but after I build the application in debug mode the application throws this error 'DEVELOPPER_ERROR'.

I have tried reconfiguring google services and generating new sha1 keys but nothing worked.

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37376939/google-sign-in-android-with-firebase-statuscode-developer-error) helps you?

Comment: @NoNam4 I tried the same steps and verified the package name and sha1 key but nothing.

Comment: Have you tryed updating your `service.json` file? Try download0ing a new one from firebase console. In my RN App I'm using 2 json files, one for dev console and one for prod console, som make sure you're using the right json file in build process. Also try adding google play store sha1 to your sha1 keys. In my app I have 3 sha1 keys, one from play store, one from expo and one from signingReport

Comment: yes I tried updating it and redownloaded the file. Also I m only working with the dev google-services.json and have Updated the sha1 keys in all consoles.