# Android Studio generate the same SHA1 for debug and release mode

Tags: android, googlesigninaccount

I have implemented google+ sign in, in debug mode it works, but when i have added my app in playstore and tried to generate Sha1 for release mode the Sha1 are the same..

I have tried:

Open Android Studio,
Open Project,
Open Build variants,
build variant--> release,
Click on Gradle (From Right Side Panel),
Click on Refresh (Click on Refresh from Gradle Bar ),
Click on  Project ( Project Name form List),
Click on Tasks/Android,
Double Click on signingReport ,

I have also tried to clean and rebuild app still the same thing..
Is anything else i can do for that ??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727912/sha-1-fingerprint-of-keystore-certificate