# Google Signin not working after SignedApk

Tags: android, google-plus, sha1

I have done Google Plus Integration.
Google Plus Signin works fine before signing apk.

Once I have Signed my apk, i could not login/signin to Google plus.

Is it problem of SHA1 key ?
Please, Guide me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While creating a firebase/google cloud project you have provided a SHA1 signature certificate. provably debug one. Now once you signed your app, new Sha1 certificate gets generates and assigned to your keystroke. Now you have to update new SHA1 to your google cloud/firebase project. No need to make any hanges in app.

Answer (score 0):

```
My answer:--
You have generate Sign keyHash like this .
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%\.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64

Example:---
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\bin\keytool.exe" -exportcert -alias   chayanh-keystore c:\users\chayanh\desktop\chayanh | C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl sha1 -binary | C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl base64
```

Comment: Will you please elaborate.?

Answer (score 0):

do you receiving any kind of error if yes post the logcat. Android Studio has built in functionality for getting SHA-1 check at [SHA-1 fingerprint of keystore certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727912/sha-1-fingerprint-of-keystore-certificate). and verify your SHA-1 fingerprint.

Comment: no error received sir, only i can't login to google.

Comment: @AskingToStack also check your sha-1 finger print.or post ur code for google sign in.