# Android google maps release key?

Tags: android, google-maps

How do I get a release key for Google Maps? I used my current key with a debug.apk and a signed-release.apk, and the maps dont render on the release.apk, so I assume its a API key issue.

All the answers for this question on SO date back to 2013/14 and [this page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start#the_google_maps_api_key) is completely silent on the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same way you get a "debug" key. There is no real difference, just as there is no real difference between a debug and a release certificate in Android (except that the debug certificate gets created automatically for you and resides in your Android settings folder).

Get the SHA-1 fingerprint for your Android release key and use it along with the proper package name (debug builds usually have a ".debug" attached, so make sure to omit that) to create a new Google Maps Key in the [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials).

Comment: Here is the link to get detail instruction https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup

Answer (score 2):

Just add string not from resources(@string/google_maps_key), but hardcode.

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
android:value="AIza..." />
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You have to enable Google Maps API here:

https://console.developers.google.com/apis/dashboard

2. You have to create key here:

https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient?

3. Put your key into `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

That's it!

More detailed:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/config?hl=en

Comment: I've done all that sir. It works when im debugging, but when i make a release build, i just get a blank screen with the google logo at the bottom

Comment: @BiGGZ , you have to add your release and debug keys into console. get SHA-1 like here http://stackoverflow.com/a/15727931/1979882 and put resultant key into console

Comment: I see. My SHA1 was different for debug and release. I made te changes now. Will let you know how it goes

Comment: What goes? Two key have different sha1?or what?

Comment: Yes. My debug key had a different SHA1 than my release key. So now im making an API key using the release SHA1 and il let you know if that works

Comment: Ok. But do not forget, you can use different sha1 for the same key. Just add several sha1 in the key preferences

Answer (score 1):

From [How to configure Google Maps API keys for Android](https://medium.com/@drvucic94/how-to-configure-google-maps-api-keys-for-android-1496dfba6747) by Dragana Vucic:

> Go to [Google API Console -> APIs & Services -> Credentials](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials) and click on Create **Credentials -> API key**. This option will generate a key that is not restricted to anything (yet).

2. Copy this generated key and click close
3. In Android Studio: Build -> Select Build Variant -> release
4. Open file res/values/google_maps_api.xml(release) and paste generated key
5. Publish app
6. Go to https://play.google.com/console/developers and select your publich app
7. Go to page: release management -> app signing
8. copy SHA-1 certificate fingerprint
9. Return to https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials
10. Click on release key. In "Key restrictions" section to select "Android Apps"
11. In "Restrict usage to your Android apps" section enter package name and SHA-1 from Google play console
12. In "API restriction" section select -> Restrict key -> 1 API.
13. Click Save

After these steps, the google map service will work for the published application.

Comment: Hi Alex, when sharing content that is sourced from elsewhere, you need to include the source in the post itself; comments are temporal and no record is kept (publicly) of their contents or existence once they are deleted. Likewise, when copying content wholesale, it is strongly encouraged from an *ethical* standpoint to mark the answer as Community Wiki so that there is no potential accusation of stealing content for reputation's sake.