# UNREGISTERED_ON_API_CONSOLE error when using Firebase google sign-in

Tags: android-studio, firebase

I am working in a team and use Google sign-in method of Firebase for Android Studio. However, only one person, who created Android and Firebase project could run the sign-in method. The others got this error:

> TokenRequestor: You have wrong OAuth2 related configurations, please check. Detailed error: UNREGISTERED_ON_API_CONSOLE

I have added new fingerprint to firebase and imported new google-services.json file into Android project but it didn't work.

Comment: same question.!

Comment: Any update? Same issue

Comment: same problem i am also facing.

Comment: Did you solve this? Have the same situation. Added fingerprint to Firebase and imported new google-services.json file to Android project.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get SHA-1 fingerprint of your all team members(for debug) and single fingerpring of release also, by following the steps mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727912/sha-1-fingerprint-of-keystore-certificate) and submit all values into firebase project console in Settings.