# Nearby Messages API not working after release

Tags: android, google-nearby

I´ve got a problem with the Nearby Messages API. Following scenario: 
When I test my App with Android Studio everything is working fine, Messages are sent and get received. 
When I build an APK and install the generated (and signed) APK on the phone, Nearby Messages doesn´t work anymore. It won´t find any messages... 
Does anyone had a similar problem or knows a solution (better knows the reason WHY it´s not working)?

---

UDPATE

[image: Keys]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the side bar of Android bar , you will have the tab "build variants" , change the option from debug to release and then run the signing report , you will get the release sha -1 key.

Comment: I´ve done this and I´ll get the following error: Error:Failed to read key FSF_Key:release from store "/***/***/***/keystore-release.jks": No key with alias 'FSF_Key:release' found in keystore /***/***/***/keystore-release.jks

Answer (score 1):

When you sign apk for release with a Keystore, the SHA-1 fingerprint will be different than the debug version. This prevents the Google apis from working.

Use this in CMD to find out SHA-1 of release apk

```
keytool -list -v -keystore mystore.keystore
```

Comment: i´ve done [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727912/sha-1-fingerprint-of-keystore-certificate) and it looks like i´ve got no key for release variant?!