# Google Map isn't loading when downloading my app from Google play store

Tags: android, google-maps, release, keystore

When I download my app from google play the Google Map is no loaded. 
When I download the app with the .apk file directly (transfer it to my phone and downloading) it did load! 
I searched all over and it still doesn't work.
This is what I did:

1. In Android studio, Build->Generate Sign APK I created a new Keystore 'keystore' and a new Key 'app'
2. run: keytool -list -v -keystore keystore.jks -alias app.
3. In the output from step 2, under 'Certificate fingerprints:' I took the 'SHA1' value and my package name 'com.gilshelef.feedme' (from AndroidManifest.xml file) and generated a new API key in the Google api console. I restricted the key to 'android apps' and added my SHA1 and package name.
4. I placed the generated key (step 3) in my Manifest file:

   `<meta-data
   android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" 
   android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />`
5. In android studio, Build->generate sign APK I used the same keystore that I created in step 1 and the same key.
6. I uploaded the generated apk to Google play.

After I downloaded my app from google play the map is still blank!

NOTES:

1. I also tried to changed the extension of the keystore from .jks to .keystore since android studio uses the .jks extension.
2. I verified that the key from google api console and the one Im using in my AndroidManifest.xml file is the same.
3. I verified the package name in google api console and Manifest file.
4. I followed this: [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup) tutorial 'Displaying the release certificate fingerprint'. The output looks the same except for the 'Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA'. the signature algorithm name in my release keystore is 'SHA256withRSA' maybe this is the problem?

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: i encountered the same issue. the solution is found here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46191073/google-maps-not-showing-after-uploading-the-app-to-playstore

Answer (score 0):

Its because of google_maps_key is different in release mode from the one in debug mode.
when you sign your app the release version is made then you can do following:

1. Find release SHA-1 fingerprint ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727912/sha-1-fingerprint-of-keystore-certificate))
2. Get another api_key for google maps api from google
3. Put the new api_key in src/release/values/google_maps_api.xml (In Project View) or (app/res/values/google_maps_api.xml(release) in Android View)

hope it helps you...

Comment: This is exactly what I did...as described in the steps. I took the SHA1 fingerprint from the release keystore with keytool. Created new api key with google api console and added that key to my release google_maps_api.xml...

Comment: The SHA1 fingerprint I took from the 'keystore.jks' generated at step 1 through android studio. I used the keytool with the command in step 2.

Comment: I swear it wasn't in your question :o ! but I put the release key in the res/release/values/google_maps_api.xml and not directly in manifest file.

Comment: I tried that as well... =\ As you can see in step 4 the value for the TAG is @string/google_maps_key which is actually the file in res/release/values/google_maps_api.xml

Comment: is your debug api_key is different from release api_key?

Comment: yes, I generated a new key in the google api console for the release keystore and placed it in my Manifest