# Phone Auth not working after signing apk

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am creating an app with phoneAuth Firebase, Android. When I was testing it with debug apk it was working but when I signed the apk phone auth is not working
I used this method to send otp

```
PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber (phone,60,TimeUnit.SECONDS,Register.this,mCallbacks);
```

Comment: Are you using any proguard file for code obfuscation?

Comment: What is that bro

Comment: It is used to remove unused code and resources in your release build.

Comment: How can i fix it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to submit your signing jks file's SHA1 key in firebase project settings. The way you have set for your default.keystore

To get the SHA1 you can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727912/sha-1-fingerprint-of-keystore-certificate) link

Comment: How to get SHA1 key from jks file