# how to remove SHA1 fingerprint certificate from google map in android studio

Tags: android

i am android developer and i got project from another developer he has used SHA1 fingerprint certificate to display google map but i don't want to use that.
anyone help me to remove that SHA1 fingerprint certificate and display google map without SHA1 fingerprint certificate?

Thanks.

Comment: That certificate *belongs to* another person. The righteous way is to create your own and register it at google's console.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I believe the intention is nor legal nor technically do-able.

Comment: sorry if the way of asking question is not in correct way may be that's why it's look like 'not legal and technically doable', but thanks for help

Comment: Sorry for misreading your intention. Retracted my close vote, and hope you are seeing the right way to do it. :o

Answer (score 1):

you need a `sha1 fingerprint` in your google cloud console project linked to Android project to display map and is required.
If you meant is change ing to new fingerprint, first, create a Keystore and set sha1 fingerprint of the keystore in new project, link (downloading json file) to the project code; that will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new project on Google Api Console for google map integration, you get an api key their restrict it first by adding package name of your application and add a new SHA1 fingerprint of your machine. After this you get an api key use it in your project and than compile it you get the google map in your application. 
To find SHA1 key for your machine check out this link: [SHA-1 fingerprint of keystore certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727912/sha-1-fingerprint-of-keystore-certificate)