# Can't sign in with google

Tags: android, google-signin

I followed the official guide about [google log-in](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating) on Android device.

I succesfully get the `Account picker` but when I handle the result, it is always not successful.

This is what i've done:

- I logged on my console, I set up the `SHA-1` for this project obtained with the console command on the keystore I used on for creating my apk. (newly created).
- Then I downloaded the *google-services.json* file and I put it into my app/ folder.
- Finally I implemented the login as suggested on the guide (posting code below)

**Fragment with sign in button**

```
public class SigninMenuFragment extends Fragment implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks {

    private final static String TAG = "SigninMenuFragment";
    private Button btnFacebookLogin, btnSignin, btnSignup;
    private Button btnGoogleLogin;

    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    public SigninMenuFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_signin_menu, container, false);

        btnFacebookLogin = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnLoginFacebook);
        btnGoogleLogin = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnLoginGoogle);
        btnSignin = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnSignIn);
        btnSignup = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnSignUp);

        btnGoogleLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                googleLogin();
            }
        });
        btnFacebookLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                facebookLogin();
            }
        });
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getContext())
                .enableAutoManage(getActivity() /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();
        return view;
    }

    private void facebookLogin() {
        //todo
    }


    private void googleLogin() {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(result);
        } 
    }

    private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
        Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
        GoogleSignInAccount a = result.getSignInAccount();
        if(a == null){
            Log.d(TAG, "null");
        }else{
            Log.d(TAG, a.getDisplayName());
        }
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
        } else {
            // Signed out, show unauthenticated UI.
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mProgressDialog != null) {
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    private void showProgressDialog() {
        if (mProgressDialog == null) {
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        }

        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    private void hideProgressDialog() {
        if (mProgressDialog != null && mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
            mProgressDialog.hide();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Connected");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.d(TAG, "NOT Connected");

    }
}
```

**My manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>

<application
    android:name=".other.MyCustomApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.SplashScreenActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppThemeNoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
<!-- ... -->
</application>
```

**Gradle**

```
//...
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.4.0'
    compile 'io.realm:android-adapters:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.4.0'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Some annotations:

- My `activity` extends the `FragmentActivity`
- The login `button` is custom

My biggest doubt is about the SHA-1 generation, since the other files are copy-pasted from google dev console.

I need the full-name of the account owner and the base user information

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks all

**EDIT**

**LogCat when I click the button**

> 10-19 09:32:40.974 23319-23319/utilitapps.prodottilastminute
>   I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null 10-19
>   09:32:41.048 23319-23319/utilitapps.prodottilastminute V/AudioManager:
>   playSoundEffect   effectType: 0 10-19 09:32:41.049
>   23319-23319/utilitapps.prodottilastminute V/AudioManager:
>   querySoundEffectsEnabled...
>
> ```
>                                                                          --------- beginning of system 10-19 09:32:41.068 23319-23483/utilitapps.prodottilastminute V/FA: Recording user
> ```
>
> engagement, ms: 15514 10-19 09:32:41.069
>   23319-23483/utilitapps.prodottilastminute V/FA: Using measurement
>   service 10-19 09:32:41.070 23319-23483/utilitapps.prodottilastminute
>   V/FA: Connecting to remote service 10-19 09:32:41.082
>   23319-23483/utilitapps.prodottilastminute V/FA: Activity paused, time:
>   144716338 10-19 09:32:41.086 23319-23319/utilitapps.prodottilastminute
>   V/ActivityThread: ActivityThread,callActivityOnCreate 10-19
>   09:32:41.087 23319-23319/utilitapps.prodottilastminute V/FA:
>   onActivityCreated 10-19 09:32:41.087
>   23319-23483/utilitapps.prodottilastminute D/FA: Logging event (FE):
>   user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto,
>   engagement_time_msec(_et)=15514,
>   firebase_screen_class(_sc)=SplashScreenActivity,
>   firebase_screen_id(_si)=2950491777079955672}] 10-19 09:32:41.122
>   23319-23483/utilitapps.prodottilastminute V/FA: Using measurement
>   service 10-19 09:32:41.122 23319-23483/utilitapps.prodottilastminute
>   V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress 10-19 09:32:41.124
>   23319-23483/utilitapps.prodottilastminute V/FA: Using measurement
>   service 10-19 09:32:41.124 23319-23483/utilitapps.prodottilastminute
>   V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress 10-19 09:32:41.124
>   23319-23483/utilitapps.prodottilastminute V/FA: Activity resumed,
>   time: 144716382 10-19 09:32:41.128
>   23319-23483/utilitapps.prodottilastminute D/FA: Logging event (FE):
>   screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto,
>   firebase_previous_class(_pc)=SplashScreenActivity,
>   firebase_previous_id(_pi)=2950491777079955672,
>   firebase_screen_class(_sc)=SignInHubActivity,
>   firebase_screen_id(_si)=2950491777079955674}] 10-19 09:32:41.163
>   23319-23483/utilitapps.prodottilastminute V/FA: Using measurement
>   service 10-19 09:32:41.164 23319-23483/utilitapps.prodottilastminute
>   V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress 10-19 09:32:41.169
>   23319-23483/utilitapps.prodottilastminute V/FA: Screen exposed for
>   less than 1000 ms. Event not sent. time: 57 10-19 09:32:41.169
>   23319-23483/utilitapps.prodottilastminute V/FA: Using measurement
>   service 10-19 09:32:41.169 23319-23483/utilitapps.prodottilastminute
>   V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress 10-19 09:32:41.169
>   23319-23483/utilitapps.prodottilastminute V/FA: Activity paused, time:
>   144716439
>   10-19 09:32:41.196 23319-23483/utilitapps.prodottilastminute D/FA:
>   Connected to remote service 10-19 09:32:41.196
>   23319-23483/utilitapps.prodottilastminute V/FA: Processing queued up
>   service tasks: 5 10-19 09:32:46.263
>   23319-23483/utilitapps.prodottilastminute V/FA: Inactivity,
>   disconnecting from the service

**LogCat when I select the account:**

> 10-19 09:34:49.570 23319-23319/utilitapps.prodottilastminute
>   I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null 10-19
>   09:34:49.583 23319-23319/utilitapps.prodottilastminute
>   D/SigninMenuFragment: handleSignInResult:false 10-19 09:34:49.583
>   23319-23319/utilitapps.prodottilastminute D/SigninMenuFragment: null
>   10-19 09:34:49.585 23319-25806/utilitapps.prodottilastminute V/FA:
>   Activity resumed, time: 144844854 10-19 09:34:49.592
>   23319-25806/utilitapps.prodottilastminute D/FA: Logging event (FE):
>   screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto,
>   firebase_previous_class(_pc)=SignInHubActivity,
>   firebase_previous_id(_pi)=2950491777079955675,
>   firebase_screen_class(_sc)=SplashScreenActivity,
>   firebase_screen_id(_si)=2950491777079955672}] 10-19 09:34:49.598
>   23319-23319/utilitapps.prodottilastminute I/HwSecImmHelper:
>   mSecurityInputMethodService is null

Comment: https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android&cntapi=signin&cnturl=https:%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fidentity%2Fsign-in%2Fandroid%2Fsign-in%3Fconfigured%3Dtrue&cntlbl=Continue%20Adding%20Sign-In . Check package name , SHA-1 code

Comment: debug please . any logcat ?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I tryed re-generating my sha-1 code with the path of "mykeystone.jks" but without succed, I added my logcat even if I didn't see anything useful. Thanks for your tips

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the requestIdToken in your GoogleSignInOptions :

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried but unfortunatly nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I find out that the problem was on how I created my SHA-1.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33479550/4700782) made me generate a different SHA-1 file from the one I created initially. Replacing the code with this solved my problem and now I can succesfully Log-in.

I don't exactly know what I was doing wrong, probably I targeted the wrong keystore, but that way is really easier in my opinion.

Thanks all for the help