# I'm having trouble getting SHA1 certificate with keytool

Tags: java, android, certificate, keystore, keytool

I'm trying to find the SHA1 hash of my signature key store on macos sierra using the following comand:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore $HOME/.android/debug.keystore -list -v -storepass android
```

The result looks like below:

> Alias ​​name: androiddebugkey
>  Date of creation: Oct 25, 2017
>   Input Type: PrivateKeyEntry
>  Length of certificate chain: 1
>   Certificate [1]:
>  keytool error:
>   java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.String
>   java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.String     at
>   java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4331)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printInteger(Formatter.java:2846)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2800)
>     at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2581)    at
>   java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2517)     at
>   java.base/java.lang.String.format(String.java:2747)   at
>   java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.withWeak(Main.java:3151)    at
>   java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.printX509Cert(Main.java:3182)
>     at
>   java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doPrintEntry(Main.java:1995)
>     at
>   java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:1212)
>     at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:397)     at
>   java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:390)

As far as I can see the command is working, it is not a problem with the file nor with password, it seems to me an internal error in java, is it missing some java package? I am using Java SDK 9.0.1

Comment: there are easier ways to do it:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727912/sha-1-fingerprint-of-keystore-certificate

Comment: Thank you, seriously, I had no idea what to do

Comment: I have the same problem

Answer (score 110):

I found that the problem comes from latest version of Keytool in `JDK8.151` and `JDK9`. By default `keytool` use system default language and that seems to do not properly work anymore on some languages (in my case French).

It was enough to force output in english by using the parameter `-J-Duser.language=en`

So try using this command line instead:

```
keytool -J-Duser.language=en -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore $HOME/.android/debug.keystore -list -v -storepass android
```

See also my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47181882/5292951

Comment: The same problem and your answer worked for me. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad it helps. I hope they will fix it in next releases, since this clearly could be a blocking bug in some scenarios.

Comment: Thank you! Worked for me too!

Comment: :doublethumbs: :)