# keytool import certificate java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException in linux

Tags: tomcat, keystore, keytool, cer

I am tring to create a keystore to be used in tomcat but I get the error "java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.String" using keytool. This happens only in linux (centos7) but not in windows.
I created the keystore with

```
keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias client -keystore testkeystore -storepass mypassword  -validity 3650
```

and tried to import the certificate with

```
keytool -import -alias  arubaauth  -trustcacerts -keystore testkeystore -file root_autenticazione_ATe.cer
```

The same commands and the same certificate do not show any error in windows.

What is wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check my updated answer. That solved the problem in my case.

Comment: Done. That solved mine too. Thanks

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I think the problem comes from the Keytool version included in Java 8.151 and Java 9. Older versions are working correctly for me. Try downgrading your JDK environement

EDIT: further investigation make me realize the problem on last java versions occurs only for some languages. Hence it is enough to force the output language of `keytool` in english to solve the problem by adding the parameter `-J-Duser.language=en`.

Probably the tomcat default language is different than english.
try running this command:

```
keytool -J-Duser.language=en -import -alias  arubaauth  -trustcacerts -keystore testkeystore -file root_autenticazione_ATe.cer
```

Comment: You saved my day! my problem was with the language, I'm using Java 8 and when I forced english the SHA1 key was printed out normally.

Comment: Indeed, I think the problem is the presence of non-ASCII character in the output.