# Can't import an existing keystore on VisualStudio for Mac

Tags: android, macos, xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-mac

I need to import an existing **keystore** in Visual Studio for sign and distribute an android application.
When I try to import a keystore after insert the correct password I've got an error and nothing happened.

Below some image of the error.

The page for insert the key:
[image: The page for insert the key]

The error I get:
[image: The error i get]

Any help is appreciate.

Thanks,

Matteo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [@gbaccetta's  answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46958548/im-having-trouble-getting-sha1-certificate-with-keytool), and I found this [for you](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/106248/cannot-retrieve-debug-key)

> I guess your system is not in english. You have to force keytool to run in english

Like @pyth has said, you need force the output in English.

Comment: +1.
I change my system language and everythings works perfectly.
Thanks.