# Can I change the SHA1 of an android project and if so how?

Tags: android, firebase

I downloaded an android studio application from the web that uses firebases, I've tried copying classes to a new android project, plus importing modules and adding dependencies etc, but I keep getting errors so I was wondering if it's possible to change the SHA1 of the app so that I can use it to create a new firebase application?

Answer (score 2):

Yes , you can create a new Key or modify key in firebase and add new SHA1 fingerprint generated in your Machine.
Refer this for generating SHA1 : [SHA1 Fingerprint Android](http://www.truiton.com/2015/04/obtaining-sha1-fingerprint-android-keystore/)

Answer (score 1):

Android studio gives you default SHA1 for your application but you can create your own debug key store. From your created keystore you can generate a new SHA1 which you can use setting up your firebase. Here are the [link1](https://coderwall.com/p/r09hoq/android-generate-release-debug-keystores) and 
[link2](https://support.globalsign.com/customer/en/portal/articles/2121490-java-keytool---create-keystore) how to create debug keystore.

After creating your debug keystore check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727912/sha-1-fingerprint-of-keystore-certificate) to generate SHA1 from keystore.