# How to assign Run button in Android Studio to Run 'app'?

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I followed [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33479550/1617737) to run `signingReport` in order to get the SHA1 fingerprint of my debug.keystore .

However, it's left me with the problem that whenever I click the green arrow **Run** button in Android Studio, it runs `signingReport` instead of installing and running the app on my device/emulator.

How can I make it so the green arrow **Run** button will install and run my app again like it used to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved it by clicking on **Run** > **Run...** > **Edit Configurations...** > expand **Android App** > select **app** > click the blue **Run** button.

[image: Screenshot showing location of the blue 'Run' button]

Comment: Please clarify how do find this blue **Run** button.Cannot find anything yet

Comment: Screenshot added to answer.