# I generated a new signed APK now how can I view the new SHA1

Tags: firebase, apk, sha1

How can I find the new SHA1 code after I had created the new signed APK. I need this so I can connect with firebase for some reason every app I create has the same SHA1 code.

Comment: This has been answered before. Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727912/sha-1-fingerprint-of-keystore-certificate

Note that the SHA1 doesn't change every time you create or sign an APK, it's the SHA1 of the certificate you use to sign the APK you need, not the SHA1 of the APK itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SHA-1 fingerprint of keystore certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727912/sha-1-fingerprint-of-keystore-certificate)