# GoogleMaps blank page with AndroidStudio

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, google-api

I'm a beginner with AndroidStudio so i tried to build a basic app. I added a GoogleMap activity and it worked well.
Then i added Firebase to the app, and i found that GoogleMapActivity wasn't working anymore. It just show me a blank page with the "google" logo on the bottom left.
I tried to run the program on a virtual device and on a real one. No success.

I tried to changed the key, I clean/rebuild the app too.
The fact is.... the logcat didn't display any message, not even a warning.

I really don't understand why the GoogleMapActivity was working before, and doesn't work anymore.

You have to know that i changed a lot of **dependencies** when i added Firebase. Maybe it is a problem of SDK versioning ? I don't know...

Here is my **permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml** :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>


    <permission
        android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.barcodelibrary.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Of course, i have a valid Google API key looking like this in the **google_maps_api.xml** file.

```
<string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false">[i have a real key but i don't know if i can show it here ?]</string>
```

Here is my **build.gradle (module:app)** file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.kandel.myandroidapp"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:15.0.1'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

## EDIT1 : Adding my GoogleMapActivity code

As you can see, it is the basic activity provided by AndroidStudio.
Do i miss something ?

```
package com.kandel.myandroidapp;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

## EDIT 2 : Adding my Activity_maps.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity" />
```

Comment: You need to add `<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="Your key" />` into manifest

Answer (score 0):

When you add firebase you have to add its `google-services.json` to project. The google map use the key inside that file after adding firebase to project

Comment: I already add it. Firebase is working well, that's not the point. The problem is about GoogleMap

Comment: @HugoKandel ok. maybe that's because of `    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'` use 15.0.1 instead of 12.0.1 version

Comment: Yes, it's because 12.0.1 is the "highest" version possible. The 15.0.1 version of "play-service" doesn't exist. It is different from **play-services-map**, which had a 15.0.1

Comment: Can you explain why you need the play-services because when you add it's childs you don't need to add the core library

Comment: @MRah I edit the post with my GoogleMapActivity.java file.

Comment: @masoudvali I keep the play-services because i used it before, but i already noticed that it's not necessary anymore. I tried with it, without it, only with the first, only with play-services-maps.... No success.

Comment: try generating new key on google developer console and add it to your project

Comment: @HugoKandel is google play services available in the emulator or device you are testing?

Comment: Yep. As i said, the GoogleMapActivity worked before i tried to install Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

add this in your manifest file

```
 ` <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="Your Api key" />`
```

for more detail visit [google map api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/signup)

Comment: Oh i'm sorry, i just forgot to add it on the post ! But i already get this line on my program. I edit my post so that you can see

Comment: post your MapsActivity xml

Comment: Done. As you can see, it is the basic file from AndroidStudio

Comment: check that you enable api key or not in developer console also check the SHA-1

Comment: I'm a beginner so... What is SHA-1 ?

Answer (score 0):

You should add your SHA-1 fingerprint while generating a key , you will get it from your android studio or from the command line. You can go through the following link to generate it and use it while generating the key of the map.

[SHA-1 fingerprint of keystore certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727912/sha-1-fingerprint-of-keystore-certificate)

steps to generate it using android studio :

1. Go to the gradle file on the right side of android studio.
2. Expand your project
3. Go to app folder and click on android
4. Select the signing report to generate it.
   5)You can find it in the Run space at the bottom with a keyword of SHA1