# Unity IAP not initialized on Android device

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase, google-play-console

So I have configured my Unity game with google play service, activated the IAP, and entered the RSA public key and everything seems OK. When I try the IAP in the Unity editor, things are fine, but when I install the apk on the device and try it there, it seems that the Purchaser is not initialized. This is the code in Purchaser.cs:

```
private bool IsInitialized()
{
    return (StoreController != null && StoreExtensionProvider != null);
}
```

And I know as a fact that both `StoreController` and `StoreExtensionProvider` are null. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks  like SHA encryption isn't working properly.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727912/sha-1-fingerprint-of-keystore-certificate

Comment: Could you find the exact error within logcat file?

Comment: @Johnny How can I find the logcat in the device?