# Do I need to have Google Play Account to make google sign in locally for testing purpose in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-play

I am working on Flutter application and I am trying to make google signIn using firebase and google_sign_in plugin. The code throws an error:

```
    PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null)
```

And some of developer asks for linking to Google Play account. I am confused that Do I need Google Play Developer account for that purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add your SHA-1 key to the firebase console?

1. First, get your SHA-1 debug key. [Great Answer to get SHA-1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15727931/4712391)
2. Then add it to your firebase console

> com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10

Taken from the docs [Error Codes](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/CommonStatusCodes)

> public static final int DEVELOPER_ERROR The application is
>   misconfigured. This error is not recoverable and will be treated as
>   fatal. The developer should look at the logs after this to determine
>   more actionable information.
>
> Constant Value: 10

[image]