# unable to debug my app on a device, it starts writing console instead

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, adb, sha

Before I did what I am going to explain everything worked fine.

I needed to get my app SHA1 and I followed the instructions of this post:

[SHA-1 fingerprint of keystore certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727912/sha-1-fingerprint-of-keystore-certificate)

Specifically I:

- Clicked on the "Gradle" menu on the right of Android Studio
- Navigated :app > Tasks > Android
- Double clicked on "signingReport" menu voice

Indeed the command "signingReport" was executed and in the console I got SHA1 code (both for debug and for release).

My problem is that right now I am not able to debug my app in the device anymore.
If I click on the "Debug" button of the top menu of Android Studio it calls "signingReport" command execute, instead of let me choose the device to debug app with.

I do not know howto comeback to the previous debug option.

**UPDATED**

I solved: what I've done is just going to the "Gradle" menu on the right and delete all "Run configuration" voices that Android Studio created after I run the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have the signingReport selected as the current 'run configuration'.  If you look up in the top menu bar of Android studio, you'll see a lot of little icons on the right side.  If you go to the third icon from the left side of the group, you will see a little down-pointing arrow.  I'm guessing it will also have the text signingReport.  Click the down arrow and select the 'app' run configuration.  Then, hitting play should start the App and prompt for a device.