# Expo Google-Sign-In DEVELOPER_ERROR

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, google-signin

I developed a React Native app, and I am using Expo Google-Sign-In for my Firebase authentication. I receive the error "DEVELOPER_ERROR" when I attempt authentication on my standalone APK on Android.

Initially, I was using "Expo Google", however that is
now deprecated and my sign-in button did not do anything on my standalone APK. With Expo Google method, I found that I had to set the androidStandaloneAppClientId. Even after that, the sign-in got stuck at the Google homepage after authentication. I tried the solution of using a custom redirect URI, as in

redirectUrl: `${AppAuth.OAuthRedirect}:/oauth2redirect/google`

but that resulted in another error: redirect_uri mismatch.

I switched to the Expo Google-Sign-In library instead, and that is giving me a DEVELOPER_ERROR every time I try to authenticate.

After that, I have tried:

- downloading the google-services.json and using it in my app
- setting the SHA1 fingerprint in google-services.json and in Firebase
- setting the certificateHash inside android.configuration.certificate hash inside my app.json to my SHA1 fingerprint.
- checking and making sure package names are set properly

I tried anything else I may have failed to mention from the existing threads involving DEVELOPER_ERROR in Expo Google-Sign-In.

The variables I mention in my code below are from the following:

SHA1 was generated and used to create my credential, and is the fingerprint used in my OAuth Android Client ID.

The client ID I reference throughout my files is the ID of my OAuth Web client ID. However, I also tried using the Android one and that did not change anything.

"CurrentKey" in api_key is the API key from my Firebase project.

This is a link to my Google Credentials page.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVfO2.jpg

/* My app.json: */

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "AssistiveNote",
    "privacy": "public",
    "description": "A note app for people who have trouble reading text.",
    "slug": "assistivenote",

    "sdkVersion": "33.0.0",
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./screens/images/icon.png",


    "ios": {
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.danyalbabar.assistivenote"
    },

    "android": {
      "versionCode": 2,
      "package": "com.danyalbabar.assistivenote",
      "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json",
      "permissions": [ " " ],
      "config": {
        "googleSignIn": {
            "certificateHash": "XXXX"
        }
      }
    }

  }
}
```

My google-services.json:

```
  {
  "project_info": {
    "project_number": "XXXX",
    "firebase_url": "https://era-gvision.firebaseio.com",
    "project_id": "era-gvision",
    "storage_bucket": "era-gvision.appspot.com"
  },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "XXXX",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "com.danyalbabar.assistivenote"
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [
        {
          "client_id": "XXXX",
          "client_type": 3
        }
      ],
      "api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "XXXX"
        }
      ],
      "services": {
        "appinvite_service": {
          "other_platform_oauth_client": [
            {
              "client_id": "XXXX",
              "client_type": 3
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "configuration_version": "1"
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Overall it seemed like there was a lot of broken behaviour with this API and it is now deprecated. I moved on to use email/password authentication at the time, but there are now updated Expo APIs that are implemented in new ways.

https://docs.expo.io/guides/authentication/

Answer (score 7):

### `eas` November 2022 update (android)

If you are using `eas` and getting `DEVELOPER_ERROR`:

- run `eas credentials` (follow the steps to get your SHA1)
- Add the SHA1 to your android app in the firebase console (https://console.firebase.google.com/project/YOUR_FIREBASE_APP_ID/settings/general/)
- download the `google-services.json` (same URL from above) and place it inside your project folder
- update your `app.json` to include `expo.android.googleServicesFile: "./path/to/google-services.json"`
- Also inside the `app.json`: double check that the `expo.android.package` matches the package from the googleServicesFile
- Make sure to initialize the google sign without any arguments for android `GoogleSignin.configure()`

#### If it still doesn't work

- Download your apk
- run `keytool -printcert -jarfile app.apk` (will print the SHA1)
- Double check that the printed SHA1 from above matches the SHA1 in your firebase console (alternatively, you can see/manage your OAuth API keys at https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials?project=YOUR_PROJECT_ID)

Comment: The exact answer I was looking for. I tried various SHA 1 keys but none worked. Until I used the one from eas credentials. Thank you for sharing 

Answer (score 2):

This is configuration mismatch. Make sure that your android/app/google-services.json is correct.

You may need to add your SHA certificate fingerprint to your Firebase config. Find your SHA1 fingerprint by following the instructions on this post: [SHA-1 fingerprint of keystore certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727912/sha-1-fingerprint-of-keystore-certificate/33479550#33479550). Then, go to https://console.firebase.google.com/, select your app, and add the SHA1 value under Project Settings (gear icon in the upper left) -> Your Apps -> SHA certificate fingerprints

If you're passing webClientId in configuration object to GoogleSignin.configure() make sure it's correct. You can get your webClientId from [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials). They're listed under "OAuth 2.0 client IDs".

If you're running your app in debug mode and not using webClientId or you're sure it's correct the problem might be signature (SHA-1 or SHA-256) mismatch. You need to add the following to android/app/build.gradle:

```
signingConfigs {
  debug {
       storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
       storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
       keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
       keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
  }
  release {
       ...
  }
```

Comment: I've tried all the fingerprints many times, and I am almost certain they are correct. However, I am unsure how to go about your suggestion with editing the build.gradle file. The thing is, I don't have any "grade" files or "android" folders within my React Native project. I am also developing in Visual Studio Code, not Android Studio. If you have any suggestions as to how I can convert my project so that I can access this build.gradle file, I would like to try your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to pass in androidClientId and webClientId to the configure method,

```
      GoogleSignin.configure({
        webClientId: '',
        androidClientId:'',
      });
```

In order to get the credentials, select your project on this page https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials

Comment: This was my issue really appreciated your answer

Answer (score 0):

As I didnt have a webClientId profile in Google Console and I only wanted Android removing webClientId worked for me in the examples webClientId is the only attribute provided. Also adding client_type: 3 was required.

```
  export default {
     //webClientId: '732421745157-983dllmj1ea30oqi0j7g0ohd6veei1tm.apps.googleusercontent.com',
     androidClientId:  '732421745157-983dllmj1ea30oqi0j7g0ohd6veei1tm.apps.googleusercontent.com',
     client_type: 3  };
```