# google-signin failed with [Error: DEVELOPER_ERROR]

Tags: android, firebase, react-native

```
I am trying to google sign-in with @react-native-community/google-signing package
```

i have added fingerprint on Firebase console, almost i have done all configuration steps which are important for google sign-in like enable google-signin on Firebase console and add webClientId in `GoogleSignin.configure({
webClientId: 'weClientId'

});` etc.
but still i am facing developer :-[Error: DEVELOPER_ERROR]

please apologies for my poor English and give me a guidance so that i can come out from this error

Comment: have you added ```sha-1``` to firebase console?

Comment: Yes i have added sha-1 on firebase console

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if your build.gradle file has the correct password in android -> signingConfigs.
2. If you're sure you've added the correct SHA1 on firebase console (try to see if the .keystore file for which you got the SHA1 is inside android/app), see https://stackoverflow.com/a/72383211/11770191