# Issue in Google oauth of app_release.apk, app_debug.apk works fine

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, proguard, google-oauth

The app_debug.apk of my app works well. I can login with oauth. But the oauth of app_release.apk of the same app doesn't work. I tried using `minifyEnabled false` and the app-release.apk runs perfect. So it must be a proguard issue. Please suggest me some proguard rules to overcome this issue.

Comment: SHA1 key create using your .jks file and add firebase.

Comment: SHA1 key cannot be created for the app_release.apk, it shows none when I try to create it with signingReport in the gradle. The SHA1 keys are already added to the firebase console and the app runs fine in the previous version.

Comment: what is using sha1 key ?

Comment: SHA1 keys are already updated on the firebase console

Comment: i am saying different of sha1 key sign and debug. and upload play store your app  you select continue option then automatically generated sha1 key in play store. using this link how to generate sha1 key :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727912/sha-1-fingerprint-of-keystore-certificate

Comment: The app is already on the playstore, also when the keytool command is used, it shows a SHA that is already on the firebase console. So the SHA is already in the firebase console. Please suggest me what to do

Comment: which type of use to sha1 key

Comment: SHA key is not a problem here because when I make `minifyEnabled false`, the app release works perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to tell ProGuard to keep all your code files and not to remove those code while shrinking.

Go to proguard-rules.pro and make the below changes

```
-keep class <package-name>.** {*;}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved me