# .NET MAUI - Why would push notifications not work the same after publishing?

Tags: c#, android, firebase, maui

So I have a .NET MAUI mobile application targeting Android specifically that has implemented push notifications through the `OnMessageReceived()` method and `OnNewToken()` using an intent filter and service.

In development when I run the application on a connected device it all works perfectly and `OnMessageReceived()` is received as expected.

However, when publishing it to an APK file instead of `OnMessageReceived()` being called, a local notification is displayed, even in the foreground. I have no code that enables this feature.

Not sure if this is a .NET MAUI specific issue or something to do with firebase.
My code for receiving notifications is:

```
[Service(Exported = false)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]
public class PushNotificationFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Called when a new token is created
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="token">The token created</param>
    public override void OnNewToken(string token)
    {
        try
        {
            // Set the token name to secure storage
            SecureStorage.SetAsync(Constants.PushNotificationTokenName, token)
                         .SafeFireAndForget(false);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // Could be secure storage is not supported
        }


    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when any new notification hub message is received
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message">The message received</param>
    public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
    {
       // Code executed on UI here
                

}

    }



}
```

And my MainActivity.cs code...

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.PostNotifications) != Permission.Granted)
    {
        ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new[] { Manifest.Permission.PostNotifications }, 0);
    }
    CreateNotificationChannelIfNeeded();


}


private void CreateNotificationChannelIfNeeded()
{
    if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
    {
        CreateNotificationChannel();
    }
}

private void CreateNotificationChannel()
{
    var channelId = $"{PackageName}.general";
    var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
    var channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, "General", NotificationImportance.Default);
    notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
    FirebaseCloudMessagingImplementation.ChannelId = channelId;
    //FirebaseCloudMessagingImplementation.SmallIconRef = Resource.Drawable.ic_push_small;
}
```

**Things to note:**

- I have the permission  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>` in my AndroidManifest.xml
- 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I found the issue, seems to be that having trimming enabled, trims off some functionality of push notifications on publish. So make sure to turn that off by **Right click project** > **Search 'Trim'** > **Deselect Release**

Comment: Hi Lewis,
   Please guide me how to to trim the app, i am using Visual studio mac, i google it above topic but not build if i set trim followed way 
`<PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed><RunAOTCompilation>false</RunAOTCompilation>
<AndroidLinkMode>partial</AndroidLinkMode>'

even i set <PublishTrimmed>false</PublishTrimmed>

still not working.

Comment: GOD Bless you, I was going mad about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can first recheck if you have added your SHA-1 key of signature for the release to your firebase console.

For released version, there is a different SHA-1 key .

You can try the following steps:

- Generate your `SHA-1` for release
- Add your release `SHA-1` to firebase console
- Download and use new `google-services.json`.

**Note:** Make sure the key being used by play store to sign your releases is
also added in step 2

There are some similar threads about this problem,you can check them here:

[FCM notifications not working in release app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65488046/fcm-notifications-not-working-in-release-app)

[Firebase google authentication not working in release mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48439480/firebase-google-authentication-not-working-in-release-mode)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, have tried these steps and the issue still remains.

Answer (score 0):

While disabling Trimming and AOT works wonders, it significantly increases the file size. Thus, I suggest identifying the specific libraries that need to remain untrimmed and naming them.

LinkerConfig.xml like this:

```
<linker>
  <!-- Preserve the entire Firebase Messaging library -->
  <assembly fullname="Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging" preserve="all" />
  <assembly fullname="Plugin.Firebase" preserve="all" />

  <!-- Alternatively, preserve only the specific service -->
  <assembly fullname="Namespace">
    <type fullname="Namespace.CustomFirebaseMessagingService" preserve="all" />
  </assembly>
</linker>
```

Also add these in your csproj:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Release|net7.0-android33.0|AnyCPU'">
     <PublishTrimmed>True</PublishTrimmed>
     <RunAOTCompilation>False</RunAOTCompilation>
     <TrimMode>link</TrimMode>
     <LinkDescription>Linkers\LinkerConfig.xml</LinkDescription> 
</PropertyGroup>
        
<ItemGroup>
     <LinkDescription Include="Linkers\LinkerConfig.xml" />
</ItemGroup>
```