# Do I have to regenerate SHA-1 fingerprint certificate before release?

Tags: android, android-studio, release, google-authentication, sha1

I have finished building my app in debug mode with Google Authentication using Firebase. I had generated a SHA-1 key fingerprint for it. Will I have to create another for release? How do I do tha?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Debug mode and Release mode use different fingerprints from each other. You have to generate a SHA-1 key for release to let user able to log in via Google account.

EDIT: You can follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33479550/4316327) to get your SHA-1 release key.