# How to obtain SHA1 Signature from Android studio Arctic Fox

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, sha1, android-studio-arctic-fox, android-gradle-plugin-3.3.0

After updating my Android studio to Arctic Fox, Gradle scripts don't behave as previously. It does not show the root Gradle scripts to run. Any idea on this? How do I obtain Debug and Release SHA-1 fingerprints from the GUI?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Below steps will helpful to generate SHA1 signature from **Android Studio Arctic Fox**

1. Click on **Gradle** from right pane in Android Studio and check below screenshot

[image: Gradle click action]

2. After click on **Execute Gradle Task** then it opens pop-up as **Run Anything**

[image: Execute Gradle Task icon click action]

3. Write **signingReport** command after gradle keyword shown in popup and press enter then it will showing the debug key of **MD5**, **SHA1** and **SHA-256**

[image: signingReport command and press enter]

4. In **Run** window from bottom side of Android Studio, it will showing the debug key of **MD5**, **SHA1** and **SHA-256**

[image: Run window to show debug key of MD5, SHA1 and SHA-256]

Above picture will help you to obtain the SHA1 signature easily from **Arctic Fox**.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to go to `File > Settings...`

In the `Experimental` menu, uncheck the option '**Do not build Gradle task list during Gradle sync**'. See the steps below.
[image: Don't check this option]

Answer (score 0):

If you're on windows run

```
.\gradlew signingReport
```

and on Linux/Mac run

```
gradlew signingReport
```

This will generate the keys and show them in terminal. This command will give the debug keys. For release keys you can you can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15727931/12779452) answer. You can also get debug keys from the answer.

Comment: gradlew is not identified as a command. Do you have any idea that where I need to run this command?

Comment: In the root directory of your project. the commmand is installed alongside the sdk. Try installing the Android SDK platform tools from the SDK manager.