# Why is my SHA-1 key too long to add to Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

It turns out that I am adding the Sha-1 to my project made with Flutter, but when I enter the debug.keystore file to see the key, it turns out that it is more than 40 hexadecimal, therefore it does not let me continue with the configuration. How can I correct this?

[image: Firebase "Error"]
[image: Console Sha-1]

The error says this "The debug SHA‑1 signing certificate must be 40 hexadecimal characters.
Required for Dynamic Links and Sign-in with Google or phone number support in Auth. You can edit SHA-1 keys in Settings."

Comment: How are you creating the sha1 keys?

Comment: I simply ran the flutter app in android studio in debug to see if it generated a sha-1 key, after creating the file I went to the following link [link](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth?authuser=4) to put the first command for the cmd where it showed me the console with that long sha-1

Comment: Try to generate by following this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727912/sha-1-fingerprint-of-keystore-certificate

Comment: Go to your android directory and run `./gradlew signingReport`