# google reset new key certificate for me but certificate not working

Tags: android, flutter, google-play-console

i am reset my certificate APK google play console... so google give me information:

the new key will usable from 2022-02-04 17:12:58 UTC

but until now I can't replace my certificate, it says that I entered the old certificate, even though Google has told Google to replace it with a new one, what should I do?
I've contacted the Google developer, but so far they haven't been answered

best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you reset the upload key, you were given instructions to generate a new keystore. You need to sign your APK or AAB using that new keystore. For that, you will need to update the path to they keystore in your build.gradle file (or signing configuration of whichever build system you use).

If this still doesn't work, go to the "App Integrity" page in the Play Console, and look at the SHA1 of the "Upload certificate", and compare that with the SHA1 of the keystore you sign your APK/AAB with -- see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15727931/4265103) for example on how to extract this info off a keystore.

If you see a difference in the SHA1, then either you don't have the right keystore or the reset maybe didn't work and you may need to do it again.

Comment: hi Pierre, I've used a certificate that has been approved by Google, but it still says the certificate doesn't match

Comment: I've updated my response. PTAL

Comment: Thank you Pierre, your answer my question