# Recompiled APK doesn't get Update from Google Play

Tags: android, apk, decompiling, apktool

I de-compiled APK using APKtool and did not change anything latterly nothing has been change and then I recompiled the APK and install it and everything working fine. However when I try to update the app from Google Play the new app refuse to update and give an error about package conflicted. I check the package name and it's the same as I said nothing has been changed.

If I install the original version without de-compiling it gets update fine with no error. so my guess is the new version check if the APK has been altered with and if it does then refuse to update.

Any fix for this and where exactly I should be looking to change

Comment: Check the keystore sha1, maybe has been changed 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727912/sha-1-fingerprint-of-keystore-certificate
Or if you have the original, re-sign it

Answer (score 0):

I think that is the point of signing, security, that a banking app for example could not be updated and replaced with the same code installed from someone else that could read passwords/tokens from the app's storage.